# Out of String Space in Visual Basic 6

Tags: string, memory, vb6

We are getting an error in a VB6 application that sends data back and forth over TCP sockets.  We get a runtime error "out of string space".  Has anyone seen this or have any thoughts on why this would happen?  It seems like we are hitting some VB6 threshhold so any other thoughts would be helpful as well.

Comment: Could you paste the code around the line that return the error ?

Comment: The Declarations of the variables involved could be useful too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others have pointed out, every string concatenation in VB will allocate a new string and then copy the data over and then de-allocate the original once it can.  In a loop this can cause issues.

To work around this you can create a simple StringBuilder class like this one:

```
Option Explicit

Private data As String
Private allocLen As Long
Private currentPos As Long

Public Function Text() As String
  Text = Left(data, currentPos)
End Function

Public Function Length() As Long
  Length = currentPos
End Function

Public Sub Add(s As String)

  Dim newLen As Long
  newLen = Len(s)
  If ((currentPos + newLen) > allocLen) Then
    data = data & Space((currentPos + newLen))
    allocLen = Len(data)
  End If

  Mid(data, currentPos + 1, newLen) = s
  currentPos = currentPos + newLen

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  data = Space(10240)
  allocLen = Len(data)
  currentPos = 1
End Sub
```

This class will minimize the number of string allocations by forcing the string to be built with spaces in it and then overwriting the spaces as needed.  It re-allocates to roughly double its size when it finds that it does not have enough space pre-initialized.  The Text method will return the portion of the string that is actually used.

Comment: You should use the $ versions of the functions where available. Otherwise great StringBuilder class :)

Comment: This string builder is much faster and could avoid "out of string space" errors: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/article.asp

Answer (score 2):

Text found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524(VS.60).aspx

> Visual Basic for Applications
>   Reference Out of string space (Error
>   14)
>
> Specifics
>
> Visual Basic permits you to use very
>   large strings. However, the
>   requirements of other programs and the
>   way you manipulate your strings may
>   cause this error. This error has the
>   following causes and solutions:
>
> - Expressions requiring that temporary strings be created for
>     evaluation may cause this error. For
>     example, the following code causes an
>     Out of string space error on some
>     operating systems:

```
MyString = "Hello"
For Count = 1 To 100
MyString = MyString & MyString
Next Count
```

> ```
>   Assign the string to a variable of another name.
> * Your system may have run out of memory, which prevented a string from
> ```
>
> being allocated.
>
> Remove any unnecessary applications from memory to create
>   more space.
>
> For additional information, select the
>   item in question and press F1.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jacco's response, [vbAccelerator](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/article.asp) has a great String Builder class that accomplishes much the same thing but is a little more robust. The author also walks through the solution explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are appending data in a loop, ensure that it's not being appended to itself, which will eat memory extremely quickly.

Example and description of error meaning:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are appending a string often. You could try using a [StringBuilder class](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/article.asp)

Also, it could be you have some stale objects that contain strings hanging around that aren't being used and should be freed. Check for circular references perhaps by logging object allocation/frees in `Class_Initialize/Class_Finalize`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime in the spring of 2009, Microsoft did an XP update that interferes with Armadillo/Silicon Realms wrapper. 
The line of code that was throwing error 14, Out of String space was not logical. There was no problem with a over sized string. It was a simple assignment that I even changed to be "foo" and error 14 still occurred. I think the error is mapped incorrectly in XP. 
The answer for us was to remove copyMem-11 from the Armadillo protection project and rewrap the the exe.