# How to make a random number in CLI/C++?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, command-line-interface

I want to make a Random number and contain it in an Integer... Here is my current code

```
Random RandString = gcnew Random();
             random = (2 * RandString.Next(1 / 2, 100 / 2));
                 if (random >= 1 || random <= 35)
                 {
                     Friend = 1;
                     FriendName = "RainFall";
                 }
                 if (random >= 36 || random <= 65)
                 {
                     Friend = 2;
                     FriendName = "TempoDrop";
                 }
                 if (random >= 66 || random <= 99)
                 {
                     Friend = 3;
                     FriendName = "HeartFelt";
                 }
                 if (random == 100)
                 {
                     Friend = 4;
                     FriendName = "SwagMasta";
                 }
```

But whenever I try this, I get this error...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Retaliation, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Form2.cpp
1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio   2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(358): error C2664:    'System::Random::Random(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Random ^' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>  Retaliation.cpp
1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio   2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(358): error C2664:   'System::Random::Random(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Random ^' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This link should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/398ax69y.aspx

Comment: You are struggling with very basic language syntax.  This is not on topic here, it is already covered very well in any book or tutorial about C++/CLI programming.  Pay a visit to your local library to get ahead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate random int number? (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `gcnew` operator, it returns a reference so you just have to add the `^` like this

```
Random^ RandString = gcnew Random();
```