# random number generator between 0 - 1000 in c#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I need help in writing a program that will generate 100 random numbers between 0 and 1000. The out put needs to be displayed in a windows message box. i'm stuck as to what code I have use to get the numbers in the box and to only have 100 random numbers.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried?

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number

Answer (score 98):

Have you tried this

Random integer between 0 and 1000(1000 not included):

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1000);
```

Loop it as many times you want

Comment: _"100 random numbers between 0 and 1000."_

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random(); return random.Next(min, max);

}
```

This is example for you to modify and use in your application.

Comment: If you run this multiple times in succession you would likely end up with the same random number!

Comment: I would think you would want to pass min and max values to the Next method. Then call RandomNumber, like so: RandomNumber(1, 1000)