# How to generate control number in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

- I am making a login for voters using a control number for password.
- I have made admin settings where i put in there the selection "maritime education" and "general education".
- If maritime education, then the control number generated should start at 100, for the first three number then followed by random numbers and + IDnumber.. IDnumber consists of 5 digits.
- Else if general education, then the control number generated should start at 101, then followed by random numbers + IDnumber.

How do i do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to [create a Random Number in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number-c/2706537#2706537)?

Comment: I don't think so. But i think I want to have, like this, example : `100 + 00001 + 22755`. itll be like 1000000122755.

Comment: yes i tried if.. Else already. what i need is the code on how to add the 3 values.. like the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to determine is whether they chose Maritime or General, then append a random number and their Id Number to the end of it.

```
Random rand = new Random();
string startingDigits;
if(maritimeEducation)
{
    startingDigits = "100";
}
else
{
    startingDigits = "101";        
}

string controlNumber = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
    startingDigits, rand.Next(10000, 99999).ToString(), IdNumber);
```

Comment: Don't forget that "random" in this case probably also means "unique" and you will have to have retry logic for when (not if) you generate a duplicate.

Comment: `The name 'IdNumber' does not exist in the current context` what should i be putting there?

Comment: You wanted `random numbers and + IDnumber`. Work it out.