# method for throwing dice, Yatzee game

Tags: c#

I'm creating a simple game (Yatzee) in C#. I have created an array which holds 5 different dice
`int[] dice = new int[5];`

Now, I want to create a method that throw one of these five dices. Which die that should be thrown, should be passed in as an argument in that method. So this is how I tried:

```
public void throwDice(int x)
{
    Random r1 = new Random(6);
    r1.x;
}
```

What I believe is happening, is that the method takes in an argument `x`, that randomly should throw the dice to be a number between 1-6. But I'm getting error with when I write saying : `r1.x`;

So, why I'm asking here, is if I could get some guidance. Am I on the right track here, or am I totally lost?

Comment: I've never heard of `x` field/property on `Random` class. Have you even tried compiling your code?

Comment: I think you're missing the basics, and not just of `Random`. Read the following link it should give you a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number-c

Comment: whenever somewhere in the world a game development homework is given, SO gets full of low quality questions about *Rock Paper Scissors* *Tic Tac Toe* *Yatzee* etc. I hate those times :(

Answer (score 5):

You are using the `Random` object wrong. The constructor parameter is a seed. You need `r1.Next(6)+1`.

See the related post for details: [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number-c).

What you probably want to do is this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] dice = new int[5];

void ThrowDie(int x)
{
    dice[x] = rnd.Next(6)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`r1` is an instance of a [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. `x` is a parameter of your `throwDice` method.

That does not mean your `r1` must have a field called `x`.

I think you are looking for something like;

```
Random r1 = new Random();
public int throwDice()
{
  return r1.Next(1, 6);
}
```

Rememer, in [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method lowerbound is inclusive but upperbound is exclusive.

Comment: And that `Random` instance should not be in the method. It should either be a parameter or created at the class level. There could be repeat issues if that method were called repeatedly quickly.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Sure, using `Random` instance repeatedly can generating the same values..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to this matter:

```
public class RandomDice
{
   private const int NUMBER_OF_DICE = 5;
   private const int MAX_DICE_VALUE = 6;
   private static readonly Random Rng = new Random();
   public List<int> NumberList = new List<int>();

   private static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomNumbers()
   {
      while (true)
      yield return Rng.Next(1, MAX_DICE_VALUE + 1);
   }

   internal void AddDice()
   {
      NumberList.Clear();
      NumberList.AddRange(GetRandomNumbers().Take(NUMBER_OF_DICE).ToList());
   }
}
```