# For Loops Not Always Updating C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I've run into a strange issue. When I run the following code, each of my text boxes get's filled with the same randomly generated number.

```
public void diceAdd()
    {
        int[] die = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < total.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < die.Length; r++)
            {
                //Simulates rolling a 6 sided die
                Random rand = new Random();
                randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 7);
                die[r] = randomNumber;
            }
            int smallest = die[0];
            for (int c = 1; c < die.Length; ++c)
            {
                if (die[c] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = die[c];
                }
            }
            total[i] = die[0] + die[1] + die[2] + die[3] - smallest;
        }
        strTxt.Text = total[0].ToString();
        dexTxt.Text = total[1].ToString();
        conTxt.Text = total[2].ToString();
        intTxt.Text = total[3].ToString();
        wisTxt.Text = total[4].ToString();
        chaTxt.Text = total[5].ToString();
```

The thing is, if I add this messagebox

```
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

after

```
total[i] = die[0] + die[1] + die[2] + die[3] - smallest;
```

the numbers each get unique outputs, as intended.

I'm thinking it has something to do with threading, but figured I'd ask here before messing something up.

Comment: total is just an int array created outside of this portion of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are recreating the random number generator every time in the loop, create one before the loop:

```
  Random rand = new Random();

  for(int i = 0; i < total.Length; i++)
  {
    ...
  }
```

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706537/451540) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number/768001#768001), it explains why the numbers don't change

Comment: Oops. Simple answer, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dylan I would take a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/2307070) also

Comment: @Thomas that's a good answer, I added it