# How to create 2 Random objects in 2 consecutive lines of code with different seeds?

Tags: c#, random

I want to make 2 different `Random` objects in 2 consecutive lines of code. The parameterless constructer of the `Random` class is like this:

```
public Random() 
    : this(Environment.TickCount) {
  }
```

It uses `Environment.TickCount` as the seed. `TickCount` represents the amount of time that has passed since the OS is switched on, right?

I tried the following:

```
Random r1 = new Random ();
Random r2 = new Random ();
```

And I found out that the 2 `Random` objects had the same seed because their `Next` methods return the same number each time. I was surprised by how fast a line of code can be executed. Then I tried:

```
long tick1 = Environment.TickCount;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++) {

}
long tick2 = Environment.TickCount;
Console.WriteLine (tick2 - tick1);
```

And I get 0. So I iterated 100000 times and still, not even 1 millisecond has passed?

I just want to ask how can I create 2 different `Random` objects or is there another way to generate random numbers?

Comment: use: Random(SeedValue); Example: Random r2 =  new Random(5);

Comment: Why do you need 2 randoms?

Comment: I want to 2 timers to tick at random intervals @artm

Comment: Then the random would be the same every time I run it but I want the seed to be random every time I run it @DaneBouchie

Comment: Use `Thread.Sleep(someValue);` instead of your _million loop_ .. [like MSDN did here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep(...)`. That's a bad idea.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know, but if a 100000-times loop won't hurt, then Thread.Sleep won't hurt too :-D

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim - Who said a 100,000 times loop wouldn't hurt? Both are bad. There are much better ways to get a good result rather than resort to either of those methods.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know both of them are bad, but I mean as long as the OP expected the loop to do him the trick, then he is probably trying to learn something about Random objects rather than he's writing production-ready code. So, I gave him a quick fix to see if that is enough for him.

Comment: _I want to 2 timers to tick at random intervals_ So? One random will do that just as well as two..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on [@PankajMishra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c?rq=1#3854950), try this one:

```
//Function to get random number
private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
public static int GetRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    lock(syncLock) { // synchronize
        return getrandom.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

`lock` block is effective when you use it in a multi-threading program, if you sure just one thread use it, so you can prevent `lock` to *increase your code performance*.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!

Answer (score 2):

To me, it seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because you don't need two separate `Random` instances - you can use the same one to generate all your random number, can't you? **Just call `Next` again and that's it**:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int firstRandomInt = rnd.Next();
int secondRandomInt = rnd.Next();
```

However, you really need 2 `Random` instances, you can use the first one to seed the second one:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var rnd2 = new Random(rnd.Next());
```

Comment: I have a class that holds a  `Random` object and in the constructer I write `this.random = new Random()` and I am calling the constructer for a lot of times

Comment: @Sweeper - then most probably you are doing something wrong, constructor are supposed to get called only once.

Comment: @Sweeper - use a `static` field to hold your `Random` - then you only create one instance. Use a `lock` if you are multi-threading.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ No, I am just creating multiple objects

Comment: ok I see. Thanks guys! Why don't you post  the answers in the answers section instead of the comment section so that I can accept them? @Enigmativity