# Random.Range gives "Unknown resolve error"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public int num;

void Start () {

    num = Random.Range (1, 5);

}
```

When I do this, the word `Random` gets colored red, and it just says:

> "unknown resolve error".

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

Comment: Do you have `using System;` at the top of your code? the full name of `Random` is `System.Random`.

Comment: yeah I have these: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

Comment: @TamirVered `Random` in this case is not the `System` one, but the Unity one.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it after I wrote the comment ^^;

Comment: Yeah I get the error: `Random' is an ambiguous reference between `UnityEngine.Random' and `System.Random'. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: See my answer's edit.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code at the top of your code

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

`Random.Range` is not part of `System.Random`, it's a Unity function

Comment: This is correct answer, if one has both `using System;` and `using UnityEngine;` the compiler cannot know which Random is meant if one just types `Random`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your script isn't named the same as unity's libraries and classes.

Since you use unity `Random` not `System.Random`, try typing the following code instead:

```
num = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 5)
```

You might be able to remove the `UnityEngine.` if you have the following statement at the top of your code:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

If you want only the `Random` class or want to resolve an Ambiguous reference you can use:

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

Also if you use `C#`'s `System.Random` you can use `Random.Next` instead.