# Select random number in a series

Tags: c#, math, random, logic

I want to know logic over how to select any random numbers up to six between
0 to 8 where if (0,1) or (1,2) or (0,2) got select then the remaining one number out of 0 to 2 shall not be selected again same goes for 3 to 5 series if (3,5) or (3,4) or (4,5) got selected then remaining one number shall not be selected.

So for example in series 0 to 8 six number can be (0,1,3,5,6,8) or (1,2,4,5,7,8) or (0,1,3) or (4,6) etc

This points are kind of spawn points, so if all 0-2 points get fill then path will be blocked for player to move ahead.

Here is what I did, it kind of work but I think it can be improved for flexiblity and performance,

```
public static int[] getPointsToSpawn(int howManyToSpawn, int tillWhereToSpawn) {
    int[] howMany = new int[howManyToSpawn];
    List<int> randomCOllected = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < howManyToSpawn; i++) {

        int randomPoint = generateUniqueRandomNumber(0, tillWhereToSpawn, randomCOllected);
        randomCOllected.Add(randomPoint);

        if (randomCOllected.Contains(0) && randomCOllected.Contains(1) ||
                randomCOllected.Contains(0) && randomCOllected.Contains(2)
                || randomCOllected.Contains(1) && randomCOllected.Contains(2)
                ) {
            randomCOllected.Add(0);
            randomCOllected.Add(1);
            randomCOllected.Add(2);
        } else if (randomCOllected.Contains(3) && randomCOllected.Contains(4) ||
                randomCOllected.Contains(3) && randomCOllected.Contains(5)
                || randomCOllected.Contains(4) && randomCOllected.Contains(5)
                ) {
            randomCOllected.Add(3);
            randomCOllected.Add(4);
            randomCOllected.Add(5);
        } else if (randomCOllected.Contains(6) && randomCOllected.Contains(7) ||
                randomCOllected.Contains(7) && randomCOllected.Contains(8)
                || randomCOllected.Contains(6) && randomCOllected.Contains(8)
                ) {
            randomCOllected.Add(6);
            randomCOllected.Add(7);
            randomCOllected.Add(8);
        }
        howMany[i] = randomPoint;
    }
    return howMany;
}
```

Basically I don't want to generate more than 2 number between 0 to 2  or 3 to 5 or 6 to 8 range.

Comment: Well, you can select 6 numbers without duplicates and then Sort it.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate random numbers in a range without duplicates?

Comment: `picks = Enumerable.Range(0,8).OrderBy( r => RNG.Next()).Take(6).ToArray()` *I think*.  A little hard to tell what you are asking

Comment: thank you all for quick replay, I edited question with what I tried so far ,it seems to work though with overhead and loss of performance...

Comment: added reason on why I want to do this way...Any improved suggestions would be great to hear

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks I edited,plz let me know if its ok, also it doesn't seems to be duplicate of any other question which got linked to head of my question...

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You need three streps:

1. Select two random numbers between 0 and 2
2. Select two random numbers between 3 and 5
3. Select two random numbers between 6 and 8

You can look at this post to see a code example:
[How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)