# c# having troubles with list arrays

Tags: c#

How i'm declaring the list:

```
static List<String> ips = new List<String>();
```

Code with error:

```
private static String getip()
{
    lock (ips)
    {
        return ips[new Random().Next(0, ips.Count)];
    }
}
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information:
>   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I'm quite troubled with my code had a enough of this, so i'm here seeking for some help. Answers are extremely appreciated, thank you. I've reviewed it a few times and i honestly don't know why this isn't exactly working.

Comment: It will fail when your list is empty, because it will try to select the first element (at index 0). Also, don't instantiate `Random` like that - if you call it repeatedly it will *not* be random. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

Comment: @Rob My list isn't empty mate, that part works i used the breakpoint feature earlier and saw it was being added correctly

Comment: Can you use a debugger to set a breakpoint and print out the random number you generate to see if the number generated is strange and lead to exception?

Comment: @sum1hor Then create an example with a list with elements, and show us a scenario where it fails. Because a list with elements will not fail with the current code. Since you're using a lock - it implies you're using multi threading, so I would imagine it's due to a race condition - but I cannot be sure because you haven't shown us where you're adding elements.

Comment: Shouldn't the max value be ips.Count - 1?  If the max value is the size of your array it will be out of range by 1 if it chooses that max value.

Comment: @jpaugh78 The upper bound is exclusive :)

Comment: @Rob, bah....I always forget which ones are exclusive and inclusive.  My mistake.

Comment: @Blorgbeard not entirely sure this is a duplicate - as this appears to be due to a race condition, which is not covered in the wiki

Comment: @rob Maybe, but OP hasn't demonstrated any basic understanding of what the error means, or explicitly mentioned multithreading. If it is a race condition, then the question should be closed with the "insufficient code" reason. I would undo the close if OP posted a MVCE that made it clear it wasn't a dupe

Comment: @Blorgbeard Fair enough