# how to generate a random numbers...? in c#

Tags: c#

I have a 2d arrays button [5,5] all blue color...how to randomly generate 5 red button in the array...?

```
int Rows = 5;

int Cols = 5;

        Button[] buttons = new Button[Rows * Cols];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Size = new Size(40, 55);
                b.Location = new Point(55 + j * 45, 55 + i * 55);
                b.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                buttons[index++] = b;
            }                
        }
        panel1.Controls.AddRange(buttons);
```

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c

Comment: That's not a 2D array at all...

Answer (score 2):

As simple as this

```
int cnt = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
while (cnt < 5)
{
    int idx = rnd.Next(Rows * Cols);
    if (buttons[idx].BackColor == Color.Blue)
    {
        buttons[idx].BackColor = Color.Red;
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

You will use the [Random class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) to choose an index value between 0 and 24 and use that index to select one of your blue buttons, if the selected button has a blue backcolor, change it to Red

By the way, this works because you don't really have a 2 dimension array here.
In case your array is declared as a 2 dimension array like here

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[Rows, Cols];
```

then you need two random values at each loop, one for the row and one for the column

```
int cnt = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
while (cnt < 5)
{
    int row = rnd.Next(Rows);
    int col = rnd.Next(Cols);

    if (buttons[row, col].BackColor == Color.Blue)
    {
        buttons[row, col].BackColor = Color.Red;
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is flawed, it can repeat the same index more than once.

Comment: yes i really want  a 2 dimension array...thanks a lot!  i will try the second one.

Comment: With a two dimensions array you should also change how you add elements to the controls collection of the panel. Better add each single picturebox directly after creation. _panel1.Controls.Add(b);_ inside the loop