# How to implement automatically checked and unchecked radio button and timer in C#?

Tags: c#, button, timer, icons

I need to write a Windows Application in C# but I don't know how to do some things. I'm very fresh in C# Programming.

**What should do my app ?**

- **First step** : I need to do from my radiobuttons or from something else colorful icons, these icon should random light up and I must to power off this with corresponding buttons (for exaple red radiobutton = red button).
- **Second step** : There is a timer, which start counting my reflex from lit button to power off this button.

**What I've done ?**

- Implemented radio buttons, button and two labels
- Responsible for every component clicked empty methods

**Which program I'm using ?**

- Visual Studio 2008 Express

**What I don't know how to do ?**

- How to implement timer and set counting to check my reflex
- How to set radio button automatically checked in random order and turn this off with other button
- How to show in label my timer

**My source code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Ling;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App{
public partial class Form1 : Form{ 
public Form1(){
InitializeComponent();
}
private void label1Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
}
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
}

private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
}

private void GreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
GreenButton.Backcolor = Color.gray;
}
private void RedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
RedButton.Backcolor = Color.gray;
}

private void BlueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
BlueButton.Backcolor = Color.gray;
}
private void label2Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

}
```

I will be very thankful for every kind of help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, you should use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to measure the reflex time.

Just create a stopwatch at class level:

```
private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```

After you light up the radio button, you start the stopwatch:

```
stopwatch.Start();
```

When the correct button is clicked by the user, you stop the stopwatch and get the elapsed time:

```
stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Also, you should uncheck all radio buttons here:

```
radioButton1.Checked = false;
radioButton2.Checked = false;
radioButton3.Checked = false;
```

Then you can display this variable to the user by doing something like this:

```
<insert your label's name here>.Text = "Your time: " + elapsedTime;
```

I have already answered the first and third of your difficulties. For the second one, here's a simple approach.

First we need to decide when to light up a radio button. It can be light up after some delay after the user clicks on a start button. To create this delay, use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. You can learn how to use it by going to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now create a `Random` object at class level. This is used to randomly light up the radio buttons

```
private Random random = new Random();
```

In the `Timer.Tick` event handler, first stop the timer because we only want it to fire once. Then you can first generate a random number between 0 and 2:

```
var randomNumber = random.Next(0, 3);
```

Then depending on the random number, we light up radio buttons:

```
if (randomNumber == 0) {
    radioButton1.Checked = true;
} else if (randomNumber == 1) {
    radioButton2.Checked = true;
} else {
    radioButton3.Checked = true;
}
// this is where you want to start the stopwatch!
stopwatch.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Log the time when the light turns on and log the time when you
   clicked to turn it of, using [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx). Compare those to times to
   get the time passed.
2. I understand your question as "How do I get random numbers?". There
   is plenty of answers on the Internet on that. Here's one:
   [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)
   Also, have a look at the [Timer.Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event.
3. Use the Text-property of your label to show the time passed (see #1). [Convert.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) might come in handy for you.