# Random.Next not working?

Tags: c#, random, system

I'm trying to make a random room selector and Random.Next seems to not be working, please help!

```
List<string> rooms = new List<string>();
rooms.Add(room1);
rooms.Add(room2);   
int index = Random.Next(rooms.Count);
System.Console.WriteLine(rooms[index]);
```

The systems I am using (I think this may be the problem)

```
Using System
Using System.Collections.Generic
Using.Collections
```

Using.Collections is greyed out.

Comment: you'll need to make an instance of a Random generator.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw How would i do that?

Comment: By any chance are you using Unity3d, if you are you need to mark your question as such in the tags, Unity3d has a static `Random` class that you can call `Random.Next(rooms.Count)` on but normal .NET does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your issue is that you want to call the `Next` method directly on the `Random` class, unfortunately, there is no static `Next` method for the `Random` class.

```
int index = Random.Next(rooms.Count);
```

you'll need to make an instance of the `Random` generator, in order to invoke the `Next` method.

**Example:**

```
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.Next(rooms.Count); 
System.Console.WriteLine(rooms[index]);
```

further reading:

[**How do I generate a random int number in C#?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)