# RNG unknown error

Tags: c#, random

Trying to make code that randomly generates X amount of random numbers between a high and a low value. The code also should prevent identical random numbers from being generated.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Randonnumbers
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lowrange = 0; // Establishing the variables for lowest number, highest number, and total numbers generated.
            int highrange = 50;
            int numberof = 10;
            var generated = new List<int>(); // Creates a list of numbers that have been generated already to prevent double-ups.
            var rng = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers Generated:");
            while (numberof > 0) //Repeats this loop once for each "numberof". (until the number hits zero)
            {
                generatenewnumber(); //Calls the function above
            }
            Console.ReadLine(); // Here so the program doesnt instantly close
        }

        public void generatenewnumber()
        {
            int number = rng.Next(lowrange, highrange); //Sets the number to a random number between the high and low values.
            if (!generated.Contains("number")) // Checks if the rg'd number has already been made.
            {
                generatenewnumber(); //If it has, it will re-run this function.
            }
            else
            {
                numberof = numberof - 1;
                generated.Add(number); // Adds the genereated number to the list.
                Console.WriteLine(number); // Prints the number. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure where the error is.
The program will not run and does not display any errors.

Perhaps it has to do with calling the function from inside itself on a condition? Honestly have no idea, i am pretty new to c#.c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

**First**: You are trying to use variables with a local scope in a different function.

The function`generatenewnumber()` 
has never heard of `lowrange`, `highrange`, `numberof` or `generated`.

There are two ways of fixing that. One is to pass the needed variables as arguments of the function:

```
public static void generatenewnumber(int lowrange, int highrange, int numberof, List<int> generated)
```

The other one is to declare them globally. For that you would have to declare them inside the class, but outside of any function.

**Second**: You attmpt to call a function and have it permanently change the values it is passed, like for example with `numberof`. This does not work this way. Normally parameters are "call by value", which means, that the variable in the function is just a copy of the original one, all changes are not persistent. If you want them to be persistent, you have to do a "call by reference". That might look like follows:

```
public static void generatenewnumber(int lowrange, int highrange, ref int numberof, ref List<int> generated)
```

And get called like this:

```
generatenewnumber(lowrange, highrange, ref numberof, ref generated);
```

**Third**:
`rng.Next` is not a real command. You find the correct way to do it here:
[How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
        if (!generated.Contains("number")) // Checks if the rg'd number has already been made.
        {
            generatenewnumber(); //If it has, it will re-run this function.
        }
```

Should !generated.Contains("number") not have a number ie

!generated.Contains(8);?

or a variable

```
int temp = 8;
!generated.Contains(temp);
```

---

Although very unlikely, calling "generatenewnumber()" within itself has the potential to infinitely generate numbers that are already within the list.  What if you set up a do/while() loop: something like

```
    public void generatenewnumber()
    {
        int number;
        do
        {
            number = rng.Next(lowrange, highrange); //Sets the number to a random number between the high and low values.
        }while(generated.Contains(number)) // Checks if the rg'd number has already been made.

        numberof = numberof - 1;
        generated.Add(number); // Adds the genereated number to the list.
        Console.WriteLine(number); // Prints the number. 
    }
```

This removes the recursive calls which could be causing your problem

Comment: oops, i left the "" in on that line... (fixed to remove the ""s since the 'number' is the variable for generated number.) However, the code still doesnt run... any other ideas :p