# How to generate random string of numbers and letters ,In form (2 letters + 4 numbers + 2 letters) Example AD1256Cv

Tags: c#, string, function, random

I want to create a function that returns a random string of numbers and letters, In form (2 letters + 4 numbers + 2 letters) Example AD1256Cv

Comment: Show your attempts at solving this, we can only fix code that we can see. Also, your example uses upper and lower casing, is this part of the generation process or simply a typo?

Comment: Just use the `Random` class to pick each letter and number.  If you have problems with that come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please see [ask], how to create a [mcve], and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Hint: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this-

```
private string RandomString()
        {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            var numbers = "0123456789";
            var stringChars = new char[8];
            var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = numbers[random.Next(numbers.Length)];
            }
            for (int i = 6; i < 8; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            var finalString = new String(stringChars);
            return finalString;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll throw my two cents in here. Basically, I'm using [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) to select either an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, or a number. The important insight is that you can cast an integer to a char if the number corresponds to a printable ASCII character; for example, `(char)97` is `'a'`.

```
public void PrintRandom() {
   Random r = new Random();
   // Decide how long the string will be
   int strLength = r.Next(1, 10);

   var sb = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
      // Decide whether to add an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, or a number
      int whichType = r.Next(0, 3);
      switch (whichType) {
        // Lower case letter
        case 0: sb.Append((char)(97 + r.Next(0, 26)));
          break;
        // Upper case letter
        case 1: sb.Append((char)(65 + r.Next(0, 26)));
           break;
        // Number
        case 2:
           sb.Append((char)(48 + r.Next(0, 10)));
           break;
      }
   }

   Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: my answer is less lines of code... just ignore the fact that my lines are longer.
I like your approach, it's pretty easy to read and follow. I'd probably vote this the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be using the fact that digits and letters are contiguosly arranged in the character encoding (such as ASCII etc.)

```
var rand = new Random();
var arr = new char[] {
        (char)rand.Next('A', 'Z'), 
        (char)rand.Next('A', 'Z'), 
        (char)rand.Next('0', '9'),
        (char)rand.Next('0', '9'),
        (char)rand.Next('0', '9'),
        (char)rand.Next('0', '9'),
        (char)rand.Next('A', 'Z'),
        (char)rand.Next('A', 'Z')};
var randStr = new string(arr);
Console.WriteLine(arr);
```

This would not work for mixed uppercase and lowercase letters though, since these are not contiguously next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

some clues to get you started

Generate a random number between 0 and 25. see [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

```
int rand = randomNumber(0, 25);
```

pick that element from an array of characters

```
var randchar = "abcdefghij.....z"[rand];
```

you now have one random character. Repeat, do a similar thing for digits, repeat, etc.

Comment: The string should include uppercase letters and numbers, too (plus presumably a random string length).

Comment: I assume the questioner can work that out . If not then all is lost anyway

Comment: True. I suppose that giving them the code is the wrong answer to a "gimme teh codez" question anyway (which the question currently is).

Comment: this only addresses how to generate a random number, it does nothing to instruct the op how to map this to ASCII or convert a number into a character.
I'm pretty confident the op could work out how to generate a random number with a quick search, they just need some guidance on how a random number can map into a random letter and how a lower case and an upper case are different. (e.g. how flipping the 6th bit can toggle caseing)

Comment: @Joe_DM my second code snippet shows how to make a letter from the random number. In general I prefer not to write code for people but instead to provide pointers to how to get started. If they cannot work out how to extend this to cover a-z and A-Z then they are not going to succeed in much programming anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rndGenerator = new Random();
StringBuilder myRandomString = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // set how many random characters we want to generate
{
    bool isAlpha = Convert.ToBoolean(rndGenerator.Next(0, 2));
    int rndNumber = isAlpha ? rndGenerator.Next(0, 26) : rndGenerator.Next(0, 10); // set the boundry 26 letters in alphabet, 10 numbers
    if (isAlpha)
    {
        bool isUpper = Convert.ToBoolean(rndGenerator.Next(0, 2));
        rndNumber += isUpper ? 65 : 97; // add an offset of 65 which gets us to an A in the ASCII table, 97 is same for a
    }

    myRandomString.Append(isAlpha ? ((char)rndNumber).ToString() : rndNumber.ToString() );
}

Console.WriteLine(myRandomString.ToString());
```