# C# Selenium click a random button when i have two radio buttons

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a script that types some random data in a form but on the page i also have the options to select the gender: Male / Female, each gender is in a radion button (different id's/xpath etc) how can i make the button selection random?.
Lets say button Male has id = 12 and button female has id = 23
How can i make it select 12 or 23 or xpath 1 vs xpath2

Comment: Do you want a c# code for it ? do you want to select random male or female for radio button in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

Comment: I can go with what Miguel said, i know how to write that in C#. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can generate a random 0 or 1 where if it is 0 select man, if it is 1 woman,
for example:

**JAVA**

Random

```
int max = 1
int min = 0

int num = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min

if(num == 1){

    driver.findElement(By.Xpath("/WOMEN"))

}else{

    driver.findElement(By.Xpath("/MEN"))
```

}

**OR**

in your xpath:

```
public By womenOrMen(value){

return By.Xpath("//div/div/div/span[1]/input[@id='"+ value +"']");

}
```

Comment: OP is looking for C# answers