# Play random sound upon each trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a game when the user hits itself to the right or the left edge, there will be a sound, like oph, ouch, Oh No, and so on. I want that to be a random sound (random pick) each time.

here is the piece of code where we determine the sound name. In the following snippet **hit1** is the sound name, one of them (as is determined in Elements).  This code works well. The code comes from "controller.cs"

Note: Inside Unity there is an area in _Manager Prefab (`_Manager/Audios Manager Script/Music Clips/Elements[Audio Clip, Sound Name, Volume]`) which this sound name and any other one is listed.

```
else 
{
    if (!iFly && !iJump)
    {
        animationManager.animationState = animationManager.TurnRight;
        AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound("hit1");
    }
}
```

I've been trying to do it like this but it doesn't work by listing remaining sound names `"hit1","hit2","hit3","hit4"` inside a Random (), like this `Random("hit1","hit2","hit3","hit4")` hoping it works. But of course it didn't work.

Ok, here is how the code looks like now, which is not working.

```
else 
{
    if (!iFly && !iJump)
    {
        animationManager.animationState = animationManager.TurnRight;
        AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound(Random("hit1","hit2","hit3","hit4"));
    }
}
```

To clarify, really the code responsible for this part is only this one `AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound("hit1");`. I could be wrong though.

Comment: So, your question is basically how to get a random item from an array? Google this and you should be able to use that knowledge to modify it for this to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto 
It's really hard for me to follow other guides, appreciate a more direct answer,

Comment: @Malsh An answer from SO will still only be a guide: we are not a code writing service.

Comment: Are you able to play a specific sound effect?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues
Yes, when I write like this "AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound("hit1");" I can play the sound named hit1. 
However, if I were to play many sound and write it like this "AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound(Random("hit1","hit2","hit3","hit4"));", I can't play sound, but also get error.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**!
I had to put `public string hits;` under `public class Controller : MonoBehaviour`. Like bellow.

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    public string hits;
```

And this is how the code looks like now

```
} else {
            if (!iFly && !iJump){
                string[] hits = { "hit1", "hit2", "hit3", "hit4", "hit5" };  
                animationManager.animationState = animationManager.TurnRight;
                AudiosManager.instance.PlayingSound(this.hits = hits[Mathf.FloorToInt (Random.Range(0,5))]);
            }
        }
```

So, as you can see, I've added this `string[] hits = { "hit1", "hit2", "hit3", "hit4", "hit5" };` to define my strings, any number of them it be, and this `this.hits = hits[Mathf.FloorToInt (Random.Range(0,5))]` to call a random string each time.

**Thansks for all of you who tried to help me in the process!**