# Any way to get random items from a large list without shuffling the entire thing?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with over 5,000,000 items in it. I want to take a random 2,000 items from the list. Is there any way to do this in an efficient manner without shuffling the entire thing first?

I have tried using he PickRandom per below but it shuffles the entire list first, which is taking way too much time and I feel is unnecessary.

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static T PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.PickRandom(1).Single();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        return source.Shuffle().Take(count);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(x => System.Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is not a proper shuffle nor an ideal way to randomize.  An actual Fisher-Yates shuffle is likely to be faster, but the 5 million items is likely the issue.

Comment: Duplicates allowed in returned result or not?

Comment: Back to basics.  Shuffle() works on the entire collection but you only need to shuffle the first 2000 items.  So re-implement Fisher-Yates and quit early.

Comment: Apparently the "correct" way to do this is to use Vitter's "Method D", which samples in `O(k)` time where `k` is the number of items to be sampled. The actual algorithm is quite complex, but there is an implementation of it presented here: https://getkerf.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/the-best-algorithm-no-one-knows-about/

Answer (score 1):

Generate 2,000 [random integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number) between 0 and 499,999 inclusive, and use them as indices into your large array.

You will need to add a bit of deduplication logic to ensure you didn't accidentally choose the same number twice. In this example I use LINQ-fu to create a distinct list and take the first 2,000.

```
var random = new Random();
int[] indices;
while (true)
{
    indices = Enumerable.Range(0,3000)
        .Select
        (
            i => random.Next(0, myLargeArray.GetUpperBound(0)) 
        )
        .Distinct()
        .Take(2000)
        .ToArray();
    if (indices.Length == 2000) break;
}
var randomItems = indices
    .Select
    (
        i => myLargeArray[i]
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this can fail by chance.....  you are relying that if you generate 3000, you will get 2000 distinct items....

Comment: @KeithNicholas no it can not. The fact he does the `.Distinct()` before he does the `.Take()` makes sure of that. To John, I updated your answer to match the description in your post in how many numbers to generate. Feel free to roll back if you wish.

Comment: You can solve this be writing a method which yields a new random number from inside an infinite loop, and using that as the soure.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  he changed it

Comment: @ScottChamberlain however, if he randoms 0 every single time (however unlikely),  it still won't work

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to put a check that the chance of you constantly getting the same option over and over is low (See my answer, I have that check in there as a ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: In my original answer, 3,000 non-unique integers were chosen in order to create a list of 2,000 unique integers. With a domain of 500,000 possible values, the probability of this coming up short are about (1/250)^1000, or so small you can't compute it in Excel. But to satisfy everyone's concerns, I've added logic to my example to deal with the edge case. Cheers all.

Comment: Another simple solution would just be `Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random class to generate indexes for range random pick and skip value for single random element.

```
    public static T PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        var indexLessThan = source.Count() - 1;

        var skip = _random.Next(indexLessThan);

        return skip == 0 ? source.First() : source.Skip(skip).First();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
        var indexLessThan = source.Count();

        var usedIndexes = new HashSet<int>(count);


        do {
            if(usedIndexes.Add(_random.Next(indexLessThan))) {
                count--;
            }
        } while (count > 0);

        return source.Where((x, i) => usedIndexes.Contains(i));
    }
```

Full working console app with execution times.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 5_000_000);

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            var oldSingle = enumerable.PickRandomOld();

            Console.WriteLine($"Old single took: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()}");
            sw.Restart();

            var oldMultiple = enumerable.PickRandomOld(2000).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"Old multiple took: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()}");
            sw.Restart();

            var orderBySingle = enumerable.PickRandomOrderBy(2000).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"OrderBy took: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()}");
            sw.Restart();

            var newSingle = enumerable.PickRandom();

            Console.WriteLine($"New single took: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()}");
            sw.Restart();

            var newMultiple = enumerable.PickRandom(2000).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"New multiple took: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()}");
            sw.Stop();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class EnumerableExtension {

        private static Random _random = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

        public static T PickRandomOld<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
            return source.PickRandomOld(1).Single();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> PickRandomOld<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
            return source.Shuffle().Take(count);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> PickRandomOrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
             return source.OrderBy(n => _random.Next()).Take(count);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
            return source.OrderBy(x => System.Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        public static T PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
            var indexLessThan = source.Count() - 1;

            var skip = _random.Next(indexLessThan);

            return skip == 0 ? source.First() : source.Skip(skip).First();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> PickRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
            var indexLessThan = source.Count();

            var usedIndexes = new HashSet<int>(count);


            do {
                if(usedIndexes.Add(_random.Next(indexLessThan))) {
                    count--;
                }
            } while (count > 0);

            return source.Where((x, i) => usedIndexes.Contains(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Execution times:

```
Old single took: 00:00:01.5138662
Old multiple took: 00:00:01.0036289
OrderBy took: 00:00:00.2382231
New single took: 00:00:00.0022536
New multiple took: 00:00:00.1563212
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling with GUID isn't a good shuffle and is slower than using random.

Also you are shuffling every single time rather than just shuffling once and taking as many as you need.

```
    sw.Start();
    var r = new Random();
    var shuffled = items.OrderBy(n => r.Next()).Take(2000).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed}");
```

Comment: Note that OrderBy will sort the entire list (at least on Framework, they might have improved that in Core?), which is overkill here.

Comment: @canton7 sure, but its super fast.....  the OPs solution was slow because of GUIDs and doing a shuffle for every single item (2000 times )

Comment: That's fair enough!

Comment: You just counting how long it takes to create random order, but iterating over it will be slow.

Comment: Perhaps the reason yours is so quick is it's not actually doing anything - you never enumerate `shuffled`, so it's not doing any work.

Comment: @Iridium  you are right, I edited the code a bit when putting it into my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I fixed the function so if you do a `foreach` on the same enumerable multiple times it gives you the same output each time.

Because you are only taking a small percentage of the total amount (0.04%) of the total you could get away taking randomly from the list then checking if the one you received was already selected, if it was then retry selecting randomly again.

```
public static class CollectionExtension
{
    public const double DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN = 0.01;
    private static readonly Random _defaultRandomSrc = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// Picks random items from a list, will only allow you to take up to the safety margin of items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source list.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of items to take. This must be less than or equal to
    /// <see cref="DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN"/> * <paramref name="count"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> that will contain <paramref name="count"/> items.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown when <paramref name="count"/> is more
    /// than <see cref="DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN"/> * <paramref name="count"/>.</exception>
    public static IEnumerable<T> PickFewRandom<T>(this IList<T> source, int count)
    {
        if ((double)count / source.Count > DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), count,
                $"The number of items you are taking must be less than {source.Count * DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN}");

        //Random is not thread safe so when we generate the seed from the
        //static random instance we must do a lock.
        int randomSeed;
        lock (_defaultRandomSrc)
        {
            randomSeed = _defaultRandomSrc.Next();
        }


        // We use a separate method here because if the "yield return" was in this method the
        // ArgumentOutOfRangeException would not get thrown till the user tried to enumerate
        // the result instead of when calling the function.
        return PickFewRandomInternal(source, count, randomSeed);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> PickFewRandomInternal<T>(IList<T> source, int count, int randomSeed)
    {
        //We pass in randomSeed so if you run foreach on the returned IEnumerable multiple times it will return the same order each time.
        var random = new Random(randomSeed);
        var pickedItems = new HashSet<int>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int index;
            // This looping is only safe to do because there is a low probability of duplicates,
            // if we where taking more items then this function could take a long time to run.

            do
            {
                index = random.Next(count);
            } while (!pickedItems.Add(index));

            yield return source[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could run through the array once and code something like

```
// This is C++ style I am guessing it should be similar in C#

for(int i = 0; i<baseListSize; ++i){
   if(random_in_range(0,1)<=0.0004){
     derivedList.append(baseList[i]);
   }
}
```

Which would run through the base array once and randomly pick 1/2500 of the elements on average to include in the derived array. This would only give you *approximately* 1/2500, though.