# How to make a player move to a random X Position?

Tags: c#, random

I want to develop my first game, but I have the problem that I don´t know how to make my player move to a random X Position. Instead of "0" (down) at `Food.MoveTo(0, Game.SceneBounds.Top);` it should be something that makes my player move to a random position.

```
      if(Food.Position.Y <= Game.SceneBounds.Bottom + Turtle.Size.Height / + 10 && Food.Position.X != Turtle.Position.X)
           {
               Food.MoveTo(0, Game.SceneBounds.Top);
                lives--;
           }
```

Comment: replace 0 with a random number?

Comment: Generate a random int and us e it: [SO question: How do I generate a random int number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number)

Answer (score 1):

You can put somewhere at the class level:

```
private Random RNG = new Random();
```

So you can use it to generate a number:

```
int x = RNG.Next(valueMin, valueMax + 1);
Food.MoveTo(x, Game.SceneBounds.Top);
```

Where `valueMin` is the minimum and `valueMax` is the maximum (the +1 is here because the high bound parameter is excluded).

For example to generate a number between 10 and 50:

```
int x = RNG.Next(10, 51);
```

Answer (score 0):

For using random numbers you can make use of the `Random` class like this:

`var random = new Random();
var number = random.Next(1,999);`

so now you would have the random number stored in the `number` variable (min 1, max 999). Now you can easily replace the 0 with `number` variable