# Randomise x and y coordinates of an object in C#

Tags: c#

I have two classes one called GameObjects.cs, this initialises a object and its x and y values and my second class is Program.cs and in this I would like a way to randomise the x and y coordinates of the objects each time i run the codei.e. currently its is (10, 10) for example for a tree object.

Game Object class

```
namespace objectRandom
{
    class GameObject
{
        public string Name { get; }
        public int X { get; }
        public int Y { get; }

    public GameObject(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        Name = name;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}", Name, X, Y);
    }
}
```

Program class

```
namespace objectRandom
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<GameObject> GenerateGameObjects(int mapWidth, int mapHeight)
        {
        List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        gameObjects.Add(new GameObject("Tree", 10, 10));

        return gameObjects;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach (GameObject gameObject in GenerateGameObjects(50, 50))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Have you looked into the Random() function ?

Comment: Okay, so what happens when *using* the `Random` class? Searches in the form "msdn C# random" will be useful, eg.

Comment: You get random numbers between x and y ( where you define x and y in the call)

Comment: What have you tried...? What research have you done? This is the kind of question that answers are rather excessively plentiful online

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706537/1390548

Comment: The Random Class and it's "NextInt()" function is the droid you are looking for. Important: Keep the instance around. A common mistake is to try to get more randomness by creating a new instance - the opposite will be the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class to generate random numbers in range you want:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int minX = 0, maxX= 1000, minY = 0, maxY = 1000;
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject("Tree", rnd.Next(minX, maxX + 1), rnd.Next(minY, maxY + 1)));
```

Comment: That helps! thank you very much.

Comment: @kartikey you are welcome