# ints into text file

Tags: c#, winforms, int

I tried to generate 4 random numbers with 4 digits into a text file, but the only thing i can type to it is just text in the quotes. Also you need to type an address to a textbox, but that doesn't matter. How can i type several ints into that file? Here's how i tried to do that.

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    i = textboxMAIL.Text.Length;
    if (i < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No address!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved into psc.txt.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        Random r;
        r = new Random();
        int generate;
        generate = r.Next(9999); 

        Random r2;
        r2 = new Random();
        int generate2;
        generate2 = r2.Next(9999); 

        Random r3;
        r3 = new Random();
        int generate3;
        generate3 = r3.Next(9999); 

        Random r4;
        r4 = new Random();
        int generate4;
        generate4 = r4.Next(9999); 

        if (!File.Exists("c://desktop//psc.txt")) // If file does not exists
        {
            File.Create("c://desktop//psc.txt").Close(); // Create file
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("c://desktop//psc.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(generate, generate2, generate3, generate4); // Write text to .txt file
            }
        }
        else // If file already exists
        {
            File.WriteAllText("c://desktop//psc.txt", String.Empty); // Clear file
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("c://desktop//psc.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(generate, generate2, generate3, generate4); // Write text to .txt file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: always instantiating a `new Random()` is wrong.

Comment: *"but the only thing i can type to it is just text in the quotes"* - Your second use of `sw.WriteLine` is indeed just text in quotes.  Compare it to your first use.

Comment: a single Random object will generate an infinite number of values.  No need for a new one each time,

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I accidentally used the quotes in the second sw.writeline.

Comment: Side note: Displaying a message saying that an operation was successful before you even perform that operation is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @p0150n: Since you've corrected that typo, it's time for you to re-test your code.  Does it still fail in some way?  What's the new issue?

Comment: Also: you don't need an extra line for a declaration. Just write `int generate1 = r.Next(9999);` and `Random r = new Random();`

Comment: I get two CS1503 errors. Can't convert int into string, but i don't understand why.

Comment: @p0150n: Because you're trying to use an `int` value where a method expects a `string` value.  Always check the documentation of the methods you're trying to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline

Comment: > a single Random object will generate an infinite number of values"
Yeah, but if i write it 4 times it will show me the same random, right?

Comment: @p0150n: *"if i write it 4 times it will show me the same random, right?"* - The code you have now will do that, yes.  If you use a single `Random` object and generate 4 values from that one object then they will (most likely) be different.

Comment: Ok. Then how do i make use of the sw.writeline? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [the documentation for `StreamWriter.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline).  You're passing it 4 `int` values, but there is no version of that method which expects that.  The first parameter of that method is the *string* to write.

If you want to write each value on its own line, convert each to a string and pass that to the method:

```
sw.WriteLine(generate.ToString());
sw.WriteLine(generate2.ToString());
sw.WriteLine(generate3.ToString());
sw.WriteLine(generate4.ToString());
```

If you want them to all be concatenated to the same line, the first argument is the string with format placeholders and the remaining arguments are the values for the placeholders:

```
sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}", generate, generate2, generate3, generate4);
```

Or with more modern syntax, if you're using a more recent C# version:

```
sw.WriteLine($"{generate}{generate2}{generate3}{generate4}");
```

---

It's also worth noting that your random number generation is broken.  The code you have is very likely going to produce 4 identical random numbers every time.  Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number) for more information.  In short, you should use *one* instance of `Random` and use it to generate all of the numbers you need.

Comment: Hmm. I used the last one and i seen '8204' repeated 4 times. I'm gonna use the first one, since the second one is probably the same as the last.