# Grab Random Value from dropdown with list of same start substring value C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

The list contains values that start with "Comm"+String. So "Comm" is common in front of every value in the dropdown list. I want to pick a random string from the list which starts with "Comm"
I read the element using

```cs
var selectList = driver.FindElement(GroupDropdown_1); selectList.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//option[starts-with(text(),'{0}')]", "Comm"))).Click();
```

But it always pick by default the first occurrence in the dropdown list list. The HTML code is

```html
<div id="RPaffgroups" name="RPaffgroups" style="display:inline;"><select name="groupid">
<option value="0">Comm Group: No Member Commission Group   [ 52 mbrs]</option>
<option value="106">Aff Group: Retail - Affiliates 2018   [ 46 mbrs]</option>
<option value="106">Aff Group: Merchandise - Affiliates 2002   [ 433 mbrs]</option>
<option value="-1" selected="">Comm Group: Default Commission Group   [ 52 mbrs]</option>
<option value="22" selected="">Comm Group: 0 Comm Group   [ 52 mbrs]</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="cbShowHiddenGroups" border="0" onclick="ToggleGroup('groupid',this);">Show hidden groups</div>
```

As seen above it always pick the first occurrence of the string starts with "Comm" which in the above case is Comm Group: No Member Commission Group   [ 52 mbrs]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate a random int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number)

Comment: No as this is to get random from a list but the problem i am facing is that there are certain values in string which does not  starts with "comm" and there it is failing when clicking those strings and the value= in the list generated randomly

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `FindElement()` is picking the first value of matching xpath is because it implements `FindElements()` (which selects first if any results have been found).
So the workaround here will be to get all elements by following xpath and select random.

```
selectList.FindElements(xpath).ToList().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
```