# Specflow C# - load/edit/save xml file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, specflow

Im using Visual studio 2019 and I would like to load, edit and save xml file.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Firstdelivery25 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.acm.nl/Operations/2018/09">
    <Firstdelivery>
        <MessageId xmlns="http://www.acm.nl/DataModel/2018/09">
            <Source>ABC</Source>
        </MessageId>
    </Firstdelivery>
</Firstdelivery25>
```

Code in Visual studio:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\XML files\\25.xml");
            var element = xdoc.Elements("Source").FirstOrDefault();
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.Value = "DEF";
            }

            xdoc.Save(@"C:\\VB_25.xml");
```

When I execute this, the test is passed successfully.
However, when I open the new created VB_25.xml file, the old value is still there.

Any help/suggestions/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The element Bron is null so nothing gets changed.

Comment: The XML Element `Bron` doesn't exist, so nothing is changed. What you need is to get the `Firstdelivery25` then from it get the `Firstdelivery`, then the `MessageId` then the `source` and then change it's value. Or alternatively, you could create a C# class that represents this XML and deserialize it, change the value of a property and serialize it again

Comment: My mistake. I have changed "xdoc.Elements("Bron")" to xdoc.Elements("Source"). I ran it again but the new file is still showing the old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [modifty XML Data by using XPathNavigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/modify-xml-data-using-xpathnavigator#modifying-untyped-values).

Here is a simple demo you can refer to.

`http://www.acm.nl/DataModel/2018/09` is the `xmlns` of `MessageId`.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("test.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("id", "http://www.acm.nl/DataModel/2018/09");

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//id:Source", manager))
{
    nav.SetValue("Tessssssst");
}

document.Save(@"new.xml");
```

Comment: @Vinni Glad to hear that. If this answer helps, maybe you can [vote on / accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Vinni To get a random number, does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706537/8335151) help you?

Comment: I know I already accepted this answer which helped me a lot. But maybe you have some extra suggestions on this, if I want the 'nav.SetValue("Tessssssst")' to be a random number between 100000000 and 999999999. Thanx in advance. if needed I will create a new topic about this.

Comment: thanx I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

> var element = xdoc.Elements("Source").FirstOrDefault();

Given your provided XML `elements` will always be null and so you do nothing with your XML and that's why the result looks like the input.

Reason1: `Elements()` is looking for direct children only and `<Source>` is not a direct child in your doc.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-5.0

Reason2: `<Source>` tag has a different namespace than the doc itself and so the query is looking in the wrong namespace.

Solution:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.acm.nl/DataModel/2018/09";
var element = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Source").FirstOrDefault();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-5.0 which is searching for children including their children.

If you expect a node to exist, I'd also recommend to use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`. This way you'll get an exception that would have shown you the reason for your problem.

Comment: did try to use the "var element = xdoc.Descendants("Source").FirstOrDefault();". new file was still showing old value. thanx for the link.

Comment: missed the namespace, sorry. Fixed.