# startup text randomized it, it wouldnt let me post becuase of the name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

aight so I'm making a WPF application and it has a loading window and on that loading window i want the text to be random every time the app is started any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What is "random text"?
How or where should you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "Random" there could be multiple ways to do this:

1. Have a Hardcoded list of Loading texts in Application (or a resource like xml or database). Read a random line from this store.
2. Do a WebApi call to fetch the loading text (You need to create/find relevant WebApi).
3. Want Truly Random/runtine generated text? Ok - generate a random number in range: −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Convert this to UTF-32. Keep appending more chars and/or spaces until a minimum string length is achieved. Use this as the Loading text.

If you are looking for generating a random Integer - Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number)