# Build a simple two card generator in C#

Tags: c#

```
string[] cardValues = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K" };
string[] cardSuites = { "HEARTS", "CLUBS", "DIAMONDS", "SPADES" };

Random rand = new Random();

int randomValues = rand.Next( cardValues.Length);

int randomSuites = rand.Next( cardSuites.Length);



Console.WriteLine("2 random cards ");

Console.WriteLine("Card1 ->" + " {0} {1}", randomValues, randomSuites);
Console.WriteLine("Card2 ->" + " {0} {1}", randomValues, randomSuites);
```

I'm expecting a simple random two-card generator. I thought this would be an easy beginner project but I'm confused. It only shows me the number, or position in the array I think. I want to show the letters and full words. And I want both the cards to be different but they always generate the exact same thing. If someone could help walk me through this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate a random integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-integer-in-c)

Comment: Some of your expectations are wrong. You are creating only _one_ set of random numbers and display them twice, so both times, they will be the same. Then, an integer number has no relation to a value inside of an array just by naming it accordingly. You need to access the array, using the integer as an index into it to read the value and display it. e.g. `cardValues[randomValues]`

Comment: Hint 1: both `randomValues` and `randomSuites` are `int` variables. When you print them out, you should expect just numbers. Hint 2: just because the variables are *initialized* randomly doesn't mean that every time you read the value of the variables, it re-generates them.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues I can see here.

### 1. Not enough cards

---

A new random integer is generated every time `rand.Next` is called. In your program, for every card 2 random integers are needed, one for card number, one for card symbol.

You want to generate 2 cards but you only `rand.Next()` twice - 1 combination of card number/symbol generated. Therefore, you actually only generated 1 card, and printed that same card twice.

A minimal fix could be like this:

```cs
string[] cardValues = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K" };
string[] cardSuites = { "HEARTS", "CLUBS", "DIAMONDS", "SPADES" };

Random rand = new Random();

int randomValues = rand.Next( cardValues.Length);
int randomSuites = rand.Next( cardSuites.Length);

Console.WriteLine("2 random cards ");

Console.WriteLine("Card1 ->" + " {0} {1}", randomValues, randomSuites);

// Generate again!

randomValues = rand.Next( cardValues.Length);
randomSuites = rand.Next( cardSuites.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Card2 ->" + " {0} {1}", randomValues, randomSuites);
```

### 2. Wrong output

---

You printed the random integers, but not the actual card symbol/number.

These random integers are actually indexes in the arrays, `cardValues` and `cardSuites`. You can access an object in the array by its index like `array[index]`.

Therefore, you can fix the output like this:

```cs
string[] cardValues = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K" };
string[] cardSuites = { "HEARTS", "CLUBS", "DIAMONDS", "SPADES" };

Random rand = new Random();

int randomValues = rand.Next( cardValues.Length);
int randomSuites = rand.Next( cardSuites.Length);

Console.WriteLine("2 random cards ");

Console.WriteLine("Card1 ->" + " {0} {1}", cardValues[randomValues], cardSuites[randomSuites]);

randomValues = rand.Next( cardValues.Length);
randomSuites = rand.Next( cardSuites.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Card2 ->" + " {0} {1}", cardValues[randomValues], cardSuites[randomSuites]);
```

There are still some issues, like the cards can still be same, if you're lucky enough. But you can deal with those later.

You can start to see some parts of the code are repeating, showing some sort of pattern. Once you are confident enough, you can start try to think about how to generate/output cards efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

To build a simple two-card generator in C# that displays the card values and suits as letters and full words, you need to make a few modifications to your code.

First, let's address the issue of generating the same card values and suits. The `Random` class should be instantiated outside the loop to avoid generating the same values multiple times.

Next, to display the card values and suits as letters and full words, you can access the elements from the `cardValues` and `cardSuites` arrays using the randomly generated indices.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```cs
string[] cardValues = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K" };
string[] cardSuites = { "HEARTS", "CLUBS", "DIAMONDS", "SPADES" };

Random rand = new Random();

int randomValueIndex = rand.Next(cardValues.Length);
int randomSuiteIndex = rand.Next(cardSuites.Length);

string card1Value = cardValues[randomValueIndex];
string card1Suite = cardSuites[randomSuiteIndex];

int randomValueIndex2 = rand.Next(cardValues.Length);
int randomSuiteIndex2 = rand.Next(cardSuites.Length);

string card2Value = cardValues[randomValueIndex2];
string card2Suite = cardSuites[randomSuiteIndex2];

Console.WriteLine("2 random cards:");
Console.WriteLine("Card1 -> {0} {1}", card1Value, card1Suite);
Console.WriteLine("Card2 -> {0} {1}", card2Value, card2Suite);
```

With these changes, the code will generate two random cards with different values and suits, displaying them as letters and full words.

Comment: "The Random class should be instantiated outside the loop to avoid generating the same values multiple times." What loop are you referring to? (The code really *should* use a loop IMO, but neither the original code nor your answer actually do so...)