# Are GUIDs timely ordered ? If ORDER BY used with a GUID variable type, will records created lately come late?

Tags: c#, sql, guid

Are GUIDs timely ordered ? I mean if you use ORDER BY with a GUID variable type, will records created lately come late ?

Comment: I've always thought not, but realized I don't actually know. Interesting question (+1).

Comment: GUIDs, in and of themselves, are just 128 bits of data with a small amount of structure. There are different ways to *generate* guids, so if you want to ask this question, you have to say how you're *generating* the guids.

Comment: On a side note, if you create a table in SQL Server having a clustered key of GUID type the physical ordering of the rows are the same as the GUID's, i.e. in no particular order meaning that each new row inserted often leads to page splits that is detrimental to performance. The bottom line: Do not use GUID's as clustered keys if you can avoid it.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - [`newsequentialid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) was introduced to address that concern: "Using NEWSEQUENTIALID also helps to completely fill the data and index pages."

Comment: The **only** property that a guid is guaranteed to have is that it is a **globally unique identifier**.  That's why it's called a guid.  If you are relying on a property of guids other than **global uniqueness** then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) mockup answers your question:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Guid>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    dictionary.Add(i, Guid.NewGuid());

dictionary.OrderBy(d => d.Value);
```

Results in:

```
Key Value 
2   3624183d-581a-45bc-9d3d-cafeddaf8585 
0   4b4685c9-f163-4694-ae8c-4b83402a293c 
4   7a14d8e4-d870-4f33-bfb3-f4337b756e18 
1   b93131c7-c0d7-42b4-82b5-e3cc456214a9 
3   cfdc0bc8-7f5a-4601-a927-a759bb9e33c6
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic How so? If GUIDs were ordered by creation as per the question, then the keys in the result would go in ascending order rather than random order.

Comment: Just because it appears random doesn't mean its actually random. Lexically they're unordered, but that doesn't mean with a different comparer that they are not in fact ordered. However @wudzik provides the meaningful answer that the guids are generated by cryptographic number generation and not with any time series component to create any type of implicit order.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, GUIDs (UUIDs) are created from a cryptographic random number generator with UuidCreate. They are version 4 UUIDs in terms of RFC 4122. No timestamps or ethernet cards are involved, unless you're using old school version 1 GUIDs created with UuidCreateSequential.

See also [How Random is System.Guid.NewGuid()? (Take two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621563/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid-take-two)

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011149/1714342

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

> A Globally Unique Identifier (GUID, /ˈɡwɪd/or /ˈɡuːɪd/) is a unique
>   reference number used as an identifier in computer software. The term
>   GUID typically refers to various implementations of the universally
>   unique identifier (UUID) standard.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) GUIDs are usually stored as
>   128-bit values, and are commonly displayed as 32 hexadecimal digits
>   with groups separated by hyphens, such as
>   {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}. GUIDs generated from random
>   numbers contain 6 fixed bits saying they are random and 122 random
>   bits; the total number of unique such GUIDs is 2122 or 5.3×1036. This
>   number is so large that the probability of the same number being
>   generated randomly twice is negligible; however other GUID versions
>   have different uniqueness properties and probabilities, ranging from
>   guaranteed uniqueness to likely non-uniqueness.