# How securely unguessable are GUIDs?

Tags: .net, cryptography, guid

A while ago I worked on a web application where users could buy tickets. Due to the way our client's processes worked, what you effectively got as a result of your purchase was a URL with the ticket number in it.

These were tickets to buy property in the Middle East, and each ticket was potentially worth around $3,000,000. Clearly dishing out sequential integers would have been a bad idea. We used GUIDs as they're basically unguessable, but my question is: are they secure enough?

As I understand it, the GUIDs .NET produces are totally pseudo-random (except for a few non-varying bits). However, I don't know what algorithm is used to generate them.

The MSDN documentation tells us that [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) is fast and insecure, and [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) is slow and secure. That is, it's reasonable to assume someone could put in enough effort to predict the outcome of `Random`, but not of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

If you saw a long enough sequence of GUIDs, would it be possible to predict futures ones? If so, how many would you need to see?

[In our particular case there were physical security checks later on - you had to present the passport you used to buy your ticket - so it wouldn't have been *too* bad if someone had guessed someone else's GUID, so we didn't sweat it at the time. The convenience of using the GUID as a database key made it a useful datatype to use.]

---

**Edit:**

So the answer is "not enough".

Using [0xA3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/0xa3)'s answer below, and following links from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621563/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid-take-two) he linked to, the following code will generate a cryptographically random GUID that's valid by [Section 4.4 of RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.4):

```
static Guid MakeCryptoGuid()
{
    // Get 16 cryptographically random bytes
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] data = new byte[16];
    rng.GetBytes(data);

    // Mark it as a version 4 GUID
    data[7] = (byte)((data[7] | (byte)0x40) & (byte)0x4f);
    data[8] = (byte)((data[8] | (byte)0x80) & (byte)0xbf);

    return new Guid(data);
}
```

This produces GUIDs much more slowly than `Guid.NewGuid()`, but with 122 bits of "very random" data, they are safely unpredictable.

Of course, any cryptographically random text would have done for a ticket number, but GUIDs are pretty handy. :-)

As with other version 4 GUIDs there's no absolute guarantee of uniqueness, but the odds are impressive. So long as you have fewer than 326,915,130,069,135,865 (i.e. [sqrt(-2*2^122*ln(0.99))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-2*2%5E122*ln(0.99)))) GUIDs in play simultaneously, you can be more than 99% sure there are no collisions. Put another way: if like mine your application will have overflow errors all over the place if you have more than `int.MaxValue` of pretty much anything, you can be more than 99.9999999999999999% sure of no collisions (i.e. [e^-(((2^31-1)^2)/(2*2^122))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E-(((2%5E31-1)%5E2)/(2*2%5E122)))). This is about a thousand times more sure than you can be that a meteorite won't wipe out most of life on Earth within one second of the application going live (i.e. [one per 100 million years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_event#Mass_extinctions_and_impacts)).

Comment: When this much money is at stake then you need to find somebody to take the blame when the lottery is compromised.  You hire a security consultant.

Comment: there is a web service that is attached to some radiactive element with detector. it converts radiation to numbers and you receive them. that is what can be concidered *random*. Schredinger approves.

Comment: Simple answer: A GUID as in .NET is not really a UID, and certainly not globally unique. It conforms to the v4 standard, but one cannot really call these UIDs, much less globally unique IDs. 6 bits are fixed out of 128, leaves you with a random number of capacity 2^122. The random number is not unique, certainly not globally unique, and its generation is not secure either. In other words: It's better not to use them at all if you are REALLY concerned with security.

Comment: See a good discussion at  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10631806 .  In summary, some GUID/UUID generators are cryptographically secure, and some are not.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

UUIDs/GUIDs are specified by **[RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)**. Although Version 4 UUIDs are created from random numbers [Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-6) makes an explicit statement on security:

> **Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess**; they should not be used
> as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants
> access), for example.  A predictable random number source will
> exacerbate the situation.

A good discussion of the randomness of GUIDs can also be found in this question:

> **[How Random is System.Guid.NewGuid()? (Take two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621563/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid-take-two)**

Answer (score 14):

This is a perfect example of how not to think about a security issue. Unfortunately it is how a majority of developers think about security...

> ...potentially worth around
>   $3,000,000...are they secure enough
>   ?...

No. A lot of resources can be brought to bear on a problem that has a possible payout of **$3M per ticket**. That kind of money could attract people with a lot of resources...some very serious people. Using anything that relies on a general purpose random number generator is not very random...thus not very secure. It is more obfuscation than cryptography.

> ...physical security checks...had to
>   present the passport used...

Again, with that amount of cheddar on the line... I can get you any passport you'd like.

> ...possible to predict futures
>   ones?...

Yes. The question is...How long would it take ? *...per some unit of processing work.*

> ...If so, how many would you need to
>   see ?...

That depends on what I know about their creation...OS, CPU, etc...and I'm sure I can find somebody at your firm that would be interested in providing some information in exchange for say...$100,000 or, more likely, less.

-- This may all seem a bit overly dramatic, but you are talking about a **serious** amount of money and it should be protected with a serious amount security. You need a **security consulting firm** that can help you choose the encryption package you **buy** for this. Your client should be able to help via their risk management department or their insurer....If not, get your own lawyer...*the one you should already have*.

Of course, there is very little chance that anything would go wrong with the GUID scheme but if did go all pear shaped...How are you going to tell all those lawyers that your security plan was top notch and they should look elsewhere ?...Trust me, you do not want to be **holding the bag** if something goes wrong. That would really suck for you.

*Edit: On teedyay's comment...*

Obtaining a "Get Out of Jail Free" card from the client is always a good idea. If you tell them "We can make it secure in the case of trivial attacks...but we are not a security or cryptography firm." then your job is done and the client is left **holding the bag**.

Comment: Indeed. As usual, the client wanted as much as possible for as little as possible, so were unwilling to pay anything like enough for a specialist security consultant. Sucks somewhat, but it is what it is, so we had to do the best we could with what we had. They were aware of the inherent risks and were satisfied that their own physical security checks would carry the buck, whatever had gone before. I take your point though - if the buck could have stopped with us, we'd have been a lot more careful.

Comment: @teedyay Good that you had that conversation with the client...the more they know the better.

Answer (score 9):

`GUID`s are generated by a very well known [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier#Common_Uses).  There is no randomness built-in as well known values such as network card ID's and timestamps are used to generate them.

They should **never** be used as a means of security.

**EDIT**

It appears newer version of the `GUID/UUID` algorithm no longer use hardware address for parts of their values and instead use pseudo-random numbers.  But these are not truly random and still should not be used for security critical applications.

Comment: I vaguely remember hearing that the MAC address component was replaced due to some exploit...I'll have a dig.

Comment: Unless the use V4 GUIDs (but even then I wouldn't use them for security critical uses) Quote: "V4 GUIDs use the later algorithm, which is a pseudo-random number. These have a "4" in the same position, for example {38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0}. More specifically, the 'data3' bit pattern would be 0001xxxxxxxxxxxx in the first case, and 0100xxxxxxxxxxxx in the second. Cryptanalysis of the WinAPI GUID generator shows that, since the sequence of V4 GUIDs is pseudo-random; given full knowledge of the internal state, it is possible to predict previous and subsequent values"

Comment: OK, apparently calls to System.Guid eventually ends up (via a call to [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx)) as a call to [UuidCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa379205) which no longer includes the network adapter information.

Comment: Windows (and .NET) use version 4 UUIDs since since [Windows 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446557.aspx), i.e. the GUID is no longer based on the MAC address or a timestamp for [security reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I guess one is always at liberty to create one's Guid made up of cryptographically random numbers.  The performance aspect can be somewhat addressed by precalculating the numbers.

Comment: See a good discussion at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10631806 . In summary, some GUID/UUID generators are cryptographically secure, and some are not

Comment: This comment is literally 18 years out of date.  Windows has been using UUID v4 with a crypto RNG since Windows 2000.

Answer (score 1):

## Functionally speaking

People say that GUID / UUID is not safe. Is it true?

C#'s GUID is a 128-bit integer and it means a lot of combinations: 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,727

But let's say our attacker uses force brute and each attempt takes 0.1 seconds, you know that we are talking a lot of time, so nobody will even dare to do that.

But let's say GUID is not "safe", so the entropy is reduced to, let's say to 32-bits ( 2,147,483,647) it means a force brute attack could last

2,147,483,647 x 0.1 second / 60 / 60 /24 = 2400 days.  So, even a 32-bit GUID is safe (but it could generates collisions).

We could argue that a GPU or a super-computer could generate that number of combinations in a snap of seconds. **Yes, but generating a list of values means nothing if they can't be tested.**

Also, a force brute attack is easily identifiable, it's what we call a DDOS and there are several ways to mitigate it.

Mathematically, GUID is safe but the mathematical world and the real world are too different.

Comment: Sequence predictiability is an important consideration. Traditional pseudo-random numbers follow a predictable pattern. If an attack can get hold of enough generated numbers to figure out the pattern, he can predict all subsequent generated numbers. No brute force required.