# How to generate Access Key (AK) and Secret Key (SK)?

Tags: security, encryption, secret-key, access-keys

AWS use ak/sk for authentication.
I am building a server-client application using ak/sk mechanism for authentication, AES for encryption, and HMAC for signature.
What's the best practice to generate such an ak/sk pair in my own program, and satisfy ak's unique constraint at the same time? Should I generate UUID as ak, and random string for sk? Are there any relations between ak and sk?

Comment: Have a look at following code [how a signed url is calculated](https://gist.github.com/kn9ts/4b5a9942b6afbfc2534f2f14c87b9b54). As far I understand, do you want to have a similar option for your app? What / why are you trying to achieve? Often using default TLS is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just generate UUID for ak, and random bytes for sk.

See [Best approach for generating API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412132/best-approach-for-generating-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

Using IAM role is the best and safest way. Else if it is necessary to use to generate keypairs, you can store keys on Amazon Secrets manager with a lifecycle rule so you can rotate your keys more frequently to avoid any disaster.

Comment: I don't want to rely on aws's IAM, I want to generate ak/sk in my own program.

Comment: What language you are using.

Comment: I use go language.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use hard-code aws AK/SK credential specially at client side, consider using aws-cognito that is best practice. Explanation to your statements :

```
-->AWS use ak/sk to secure users remote access via aws-cli.
```

Wrong, this is for authentication not for securing remote access,

```
-->I am building a server-client application using ak/sk mechanism to encrypt data.
```

Again ak/sk not for encrypt data,

```
-->What's the best practice to generate such an ak/sk pair, and satisfy ak's unique constraint at the same time.
```

Just create an IAM user, give required permission to user, and generate ak/sk.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to express clearly. I use ak/sk mechanism for authentication, AES for encryption, and HMAC for signature. I have update my post.