# Generate and store API Keys for a user Casdoor

Tags: authentication, api-key

I want users to be able to generate and store API Keys or at least generate API Keys that are bound to a user in casdoor. Is this possible? I haven't found any solution yet.

I see that there is WebAuthn, different OAuth2 providers, but no API Keys.

My goal would be to have one central store of all credentials so that whenever I want to make the authentication and authorization, I could always refer to this store of Auth configs and credentials.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412132/whats-the-best-approach-for-generating-a-new-api-key

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do this in Casdoor and through their API. (https://casdoor.org/). Sadly There is no Tag for this and I don't have 1.5k Reputation to create this tag

Comment: Created, but I think you'll get a more direct answer here https://github.com/casdoor/casdoor/issues/1240