# Encrypting and Decrypting AES 256 in both php and vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, openssl, cryptography, aes

I have a need to be able to encrypt and decrypt strings in both php and vb.net.
PHP needs to be able to decrypt strings encrypted in vb.net and vb.net needs to be able to decrypt string encrypted in php.

I have working code in both environments that work within that environment, but they do not work with each other.

I've done alot of searching on this one and I believe that this is to do with the openssl implementation of AES256 and the way it salts with the IV or something along those lines.

The vb implementation is generating a random GUID for the IV and prepending it to the encrypted string before base64 encoding it.

My vb.net code is like so...

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography


Public Class tbSecurity

Public Shared enckey = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
Public Shared Function AESEncryptStringToBase64(strPlainText As String) As String
    Dim Algo As RijndaelManaged = RijndaelManaged.Create()

    With Algo
        .BlockSize = 128
        .FeedbackSize = 128
        .KeySize = 256
        .Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        .IV = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()
        .Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(enckey)
    End With

    Using Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = Algo.CreateEncryptor()
        Using MemStream As New MemoryStream
            Using CryptStream As New CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using Writer As New StreamWriter(CryptStream)
                    Writer.Write(strPlainText)
                End Using

                AESEncryptStringToBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Algo.IV.Concat(MemStream.ToArray()).ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Public Shared Function AESDecryptBase64ToString(strCipherText As String) As String
    Dim arrSaltAndCipherText As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(strCipherText)

    Dim Algo As RijndaelManaged = RijndaelManaged.Create()

    With Algo
        .BlockSize = 128
        .FeedbackSize = 128
        .KeySize = 256
        .Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        .IV = arrSaltAndCipherText.Take(16).ToArray()
        .Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(enckey)
    End With

    Using Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = Algo.CreateDecryptor()
        Using MemStream As New MemoryStream(arrSaltAndCipherText.Skip(16).ToArray())
            Using CryptStream As New CryptoStream(MemStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using Reader As New StreamReader(CryptStream)
                    AESDecryptBase64ToString = Reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

End Class
```

PHP code is like so...

```php
<?php
$inputstr = $_GET['str'];
 
$ky = '00000000000000000000000000000000'; // 32 * 8 = 256 bit key
$iv = '1234567890123456'; // 32 * 8 = 256 bit iv

echo "<hr>";
echo "Input Str = " . $inputstr;
echo "<hr>";
echo "Decrypted Str = " . decryptRJ256($ky,$iv,$inputstr);

function decryptRJ256($key,$iv,$string_to_decrypt)
{
    $string_to_decrypt = base64_decode($string_to_decrypt);
    $rtn = openssl_decrypt($string_to_decrypt, "aes-256-cbc", $key,0,$iv); 
    $rtn = rtrim($rtn, "\0\4");
    return($rtn);
}

function encryptRJ256($key,$iv,$string_to_encrypt)
{
    $rtn = openssl_decrypt($string_to_encrypt, "aes-256-cbc", $key,0,$iv); 
    $rtn = base64_encode($rtn);
    return($rtn);
}    
?>
```

I've come across a 'working' example of code that uses AES128 and the mcrypt extension for PHP, however I'm using PHP8 and Mcrypt is deprecated and unsupported, so I really don't want to take that route.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for either making strings encrypted in PHP using the openssl implementation of AES256 decryptable in vb.net or the other way round?
I don't care which environment I have to amend, or even if its both.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AESEncryptStringToBase64()` in the VB code encrypts a plaintext with AES in CBC mode with PKCS7 padding. The key size determines the AES variant, e.g. 32 bytes for AES-256. During encryption a GUID is generated which acts as IV. After encryption, the IV and ciphertext are concatenated and Base64 encoded.

A possible implementation in PHP is:

```php
function encrypt($key, $plaintext){
    $iv = random_bytes(16);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $ivCiphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
    $ivCiphertextB64 = base64_encode($ivCiphertext);
    return $ivCiphertextB64;
}
```

Note:

- In the PHP code a cryptographically secure IV, see [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), is generated instead of a GUID. This is at least as secure as the GUID used in the VB code, see [Is Microsoft's GUID generator cryptographically secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17408572/16205441).
- In the PHP code AES-256 is specified and therefore a 32 bytes key is required. In the VB code, therefore, a 32 bytes key must also be used for compatibility. In case of a different key size in the VB code, the AES variant in the PHP code must be adapted accordingly, e.g. `aes-128-cbc` for a 16 bytes key.

---

`AESDecryptBase64ToString()` in the VB code is the counterpart and therefore uses the same algorithm, mode and padding. The encrypted data is first Base64 decoded. The first 16 bytes are the IV, the rest is the ciphertext which is then decrypted.

A possible implementation in PHP is:

```php
function decrypt($key, $ivCiphertextB64){
    $ivCiphertext  = base64_decode($ivCiphertextB64);
    $iv = substr($ivCiphertext, 0, 16);
    $ciphertext = substr($ivCiphertext, 16);
    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
    return $decryptedData;
}
```

---

Tests:

```php
// Test 1:
$key = '00000000000000000000000000000000'; 
$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$ivCiphertextB64 = encrypt($key, $plaintext);
$decrypted = decrypt($key, $ivCiphertextB64);
print("Test 1 - Ciphertext: " . $ivCiphertextB64 . PHP_EOL);
print("Test 1 - Decrypted:  " . $decrypted . PHP_EOL);

// Test 2: Decrypt ciphertext from VB
$ivCiphertextB64 = '6z4IGlnv5UOd+MWUOfP5m4ymJ/XUp+VijU0D4xBLRr/T1JWAsxRApW6aJgptmN4q2f0seibD/2jktvkDydz33g==';
$decrypted = decrypt($key, $ivCiphertextB64);
print("Test 2 - Decrypted:  " . $decrypted . PHP_EOL);

// Test 3: Encrypt plaintext for VB
$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$ivCiphertextB64 = encrypt($key, $plaintext);
print("Test 3 - Encrypted:  " . $ivCiphertextB64 . PHP_EOL);
```

with the following possible output:

```
Test 1 - Ciphertext: cadDJ82W94xKz4MQlvZ4IPBYvytpJezgbAY+ZYi76Z/zcGieUFDZLzEsjenolbEP2pR9JTHOHnG+ylJCXZd45g==
Test 1 - Decrypted:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Test 2 - Decrypted:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Test 3 - Encrypted:  Teo0qUA553EJ9y9O0lb0gjVzWHE8+EQyklnbq6v8ziK5SXNAhX6HdyfdtHkyQUKAWXmFazWx2bEkIDwqjM+aQA==
```

Test 1 shows that a ciphertext encrypted with `encrypt()` can be decrypted with `decrypt()`. Test 2 decrypts a ciphertext encrypted with the VB code. Test 3 generates a ciphertext that can be decrypted with the VB code.

Comment: that is an awesome example and I've been able to get 75% of the way there with your help. VB can decrypt the strings coming out of PHP consistently, however I'm still not able to decrypt the strings coming out of vb in php... I'm fairly sure this is down to the key size differing in the encrypt function in vb as you mentioned in your second note.

Given that that code is using a random GUID, how can i ensure that the key is 32 bytes and therefore compatible with php?  Many thanks again

Comment: Infact, I've done some more testing and it seems that it DOES work from vb to PHP, albeit intermittently. I thought it depending on the length of the string being encrypted, but i'm not 100% about that now... doing some more testing

Comment: I am an idiot, and you are a genius.  It wasnt working for me as I was providing my string to php from vb in the form of a GET variable. I can only assume that some URL encoding or such like was occuring.
If I add it straight into the PHP as a static variable, it works perfectly. Thank you so much for you assistance kind sir. :)