# Call for MVC 5 Web Api 2 Refresh Token from the Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am using MVC 5 Web Api 2 with individual user account authentication. I have set the access token expiration of 30 days.

```
       OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30), // Expiration 30 Days 
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

But my access token gets expires early (i think it expires after 9-10 hours). So i want to call jquery ajax for refresh token  " /Token ". I refered [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) From this artical i created ajax :-

```
var data = "refresh_token="+refresh_token;
data = data + "&grant_type=refresh_token"   
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/Token",
    data: data,
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    success: function (data) {
     saveAccessToken(data);
    }
});
```

I have created GrantRefreshToken in " ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs " also

```
 public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        return base.GrantRefreshToken(context);
    }
```

When call the ajax I am getting error of invalid grant_type. No Clue why? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by refering the link [Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637674/owin-security-how-to-implement-oauth2-refresh-tokens). 
Added the class

```
 public class ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
 {
 public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
 {
    // Expiration time in seconds
    int expire = 100*60;
    context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expire));
    context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
}

public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
    context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
}
```

}

and added this in Startup.Auth.cs

```
RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider()
```

Ajax Call

```
 $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            },
            type: 'post',
            url: "http://MyLink/Token",
            dataType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA..",
            success: function (data) {
                saveAccessToken(data);                  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Probably you should use DateTime.UtcNow