# Access tokens expire after only 1 day oAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, token, access-token

With my project using the API in ASP MVC using OAuth, it seems that access tokens expire after 1 day, Although her expiry date after 14 days. I checked my settings in Startup.Auth

```
enter code here
```

public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

```
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDataContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "321201955415666",
        //    appSecret: "a4ebb10b8a5369c413c06ee7098449ac");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }
}
```

{
  "access_token": "scQXJFrvyPqWMz0xYLnHnmJ1vOAUt8b1ptmOeCuNsFa5AX8FJkGzpZSiBFtQR93fVzOnkBcJV3R8l3sfw04Pchfm1sx41_Zpn4GIb9OxGc1A4EnGzvQ4IHqa-9zw-hayalvErg-ETExABn2a8qh0qvZHWhy1ggfa9VDwy8fJzjEY03dNbc_azPBg4IGHDvUfux2X6cwtWkXkt8wzDKxRxou4QRmR2VHc7lFcISoLtA0wjjEtjo10yyrZolcqL5JrE2T_uw1CTvVQYjdcCs2wderQKD0MrZE9d_ql2RY4sFfa0p2pmdgVgrw6z7vTejED5ofFRyxp0sKG7pHtk1FSjX81nQyyhCFZLXWlQhy_WFxUMhJUYEKO3gTaQH2hkp9GYf10rtlrgd1iO9_ltjf0smjioUiw_pUa-kBqrhQyXgpWaqsbiDZWCzam82_lg8ED610IYcULC2981iXiaacYZ3gHrkp32eSapKvPzmGGbOPMzxi5oLgXIQedrDsCb-39mQvh3Ln32HCATPqiUAcWcA",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1209599,
  "userName": "ashraf",
  "Id": "087ee3e3-692d-4ae2-b62d-00da3534bee8",
  ".issued": "Sat, 18 May 2019 21:09:54 GMT",
  ".expires": "Sat, 01 Jun 2019 21:09:54 GMT"
}

Comment: Why did you use **Enable the application to use a cookie section**  ?

Comment: Did you ask about this line: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); To store user information and simplify subsequent access

Comment: All Information that needs to store user information exists in token data, so using cookie authentication is not necessary, remove it and check your code may solve your problem.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742253/how-to-extend-web-api-token-expiration-time-or-any-solution-to-prevent-expiratio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

All Information that needs to store user information exists in token data, so using cookie authentication is not necessary, remove it and check your code may solve your problem.

[check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742253/how-to-extend-web-api-token-expiration-time-or-any-solution-to-prevent-expiratio?noredirect=1&lq=1)