# How to create an array of non repeating random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, random, tostring

I have a lottery application in C# which takes in the number of numbers to draw and also the maximum number to draw.I have coded up to creating an array holding the required random  numbers but I need them to be unique and am having trouble doing it.I would be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on this,Thanks

Here is my code so far:

```
class Lottery

{

  static int[] numberHolder; //array to be filled with numbers up to an 
                             //amount entered by the user eg 42 Max

  static int[] drawHolder;   //array to hold the each random number 
                             //drawn from the pool of numbers eg 7 numbers

    public Lottery() //Lottery class Constructor
    {

    }


    //method which takes in a number limit and amount of numbers to be drawn
    public String drawNumbers(int numLimit, int numAmount) 
    {

        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numLimit ; i++) //loop to fill up numberHolder array
                                            // with predefined limit of numbers

        {
            numberHolder[i] = i++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numAmount; i++)
        {


            // code to pick unique random numbers no greater than numAmount 
            // and add them to the drawHolder[] array
            drawHolder[i] = RandomNumber.Next(1, numLimit);

        }





        //return the drawHolder array to String
        return null;
    }





}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, you should change your approach.

Instead of thinking "I'll generate random indexes to pick my numbers", where you have to be sure you don't get any duplicates, I would simply shuffle the array and take the X first you need. That way, you don't need to worry about indexes or duplicates.

So your second for loop would be changed to

```
drawHolder = numberHolder.OrderBy(x => new Guid()).Take(numAmount);
```

*(Please note I've used `new Guid()` so you can remove your `RandomNumber` declaration line. As discussed before, a GUID is a unique value and not meant for to be used as a random gen. You could also use `x => RandomNumber.Next()`, but if you **really** need a strong and reliable shuffe, read about [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))*

You can also replace your numberHolder array with a simple `Enumerable.Range`

So your whole code would become (And please note I've changed your method name to use C# conventions, method names should be in PascalCase)

```
public string DrawNumbers(int numLimit, int numAmount) 
{
    drawHolder = Enumerable.Range(0, numLimit).OrderBy(x => new Guid()).Take(numAmount);

    return string.Join(", ", drawHolder);
}
```

Comment: thank you for this its very helpful,can you explain what Enumerable.Range() is/does ,sorry I'm new to c#

Comment: @bIG_aL I encourage you to read the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it. The doc is really well done and pretty informative. But to be brief, it does exactly what your first loop is supposed to be doing, but with a starting value. It generates an array from starting value up to starting value + count.

Comment: Somewhat risky sorting with an unstable key, better to do `Enumerable.Range(1, limit).Select(i => new { g=Guid.NewGuid(), i }).OrderBy(e => e.g).Select(e => e.i);`

Comment: Guids aren't guaranteed to be random - they're unique. I wouldn't rely on using Guids as you never know if the implementation is actually random or not - and it could change in the future making programs that rely on the randomness fail.

Comment: @Enigmativity Of course, and it was discussed multiple times (and there's even a specific question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2621604/2316200)). I'll add even more italic text haha, thanks :)

Comment: That link you gave specifically says they they have no guarantee of randomness.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes. And in my opinion Random.Next() is not great either (but at least random) to shuffle. The best way would be with a real algorith, like Fisher-Yates. But for shortness and non-critical apps, Guid works wonders.

Comment: It may work great now, but then next update to the .Net framework may introduce a non-random element to the beginning of the guid and there goes any and all code that relied on the "randomness". That won't happen for `Random`. But I do agree, a proper cryptographic pseudo-random sequence would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like shuffling your array is better than generating random numbers. You could do it like this:

```
int[] ShuffleArray(int[] array)
{
  Random r = new Random();
  for (int i = array.Length; i > 0; i--)
  {
    int j = r.Next(i);
    int k = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1]  = k;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Credit goes to [@RohitArora](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6b3b682e-7573-4570-ac2c-4b75b7522afd/c-how-can-i-made-an-int-array-mix-up-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, you could use the `Contains` method.

```
numberHolder.Contains(value)
```

The Any() method.

```
numberHolder.Any(x=>x == value);
```

Comment: Generating random numbers only once to get them all in a range could be reaaaaaly long

Comment: You're right, it's begging for someone to specify a range that's smaller than the number of selections and loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved using a shuffling algorithm on an array of non-repeating integers:

```
public int[] GenerateNonRepeatingNumbers(int seed, int min, int range)
    {
        // Make sure range is an appropriate value
        if (range <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Range must be greater than zero.");
        }

        // Make an array to hold our numbers
        int[] numbers = new int[range];

        // Seed the RNG.
        Random rng = new Random(seed);

        // Fill the array with all numbers from min to min + range
        for (int i = 0; i < range; numbers[i] = min + i++) { }

        int
            a = 0, // Swap index
            t = 0; // Temporary value storage

        // Scramble the values
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        {
            // Get a random index that isn't i
            while ((a = rng.Next(range)) == i) { };
            // Store the old value at i
            t = numbers[i]; 
            // Change the old value to the value at the random index
            numbers[i] = numbers[a]; 
            // Set value at random index to our old value from numbers[i]
            numbers[a] = t; 
        }

        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) like this:

```
public String drawNumbers(int numLimit, int numAmount) {
    var numbers = Infinite(() => random.Next(numLimit)).Distinct().Take(numAmount);
    return string.Join(" ", numbers);
}
private Random random = new Random();
private static IEnumerable<T> Infinite<T>(Func<T> generator) {
    while (true) yield return generator();
}
```

In most lotteries where `numLimit` is large and `numAmount` is 10 or less, this method is more efficient than creating and shuffling an array of length `numLimit`.

If real money is involved, you should use a better randomness generator than `Random` or `Guid`. Here's a full `Lottery` class that uses [a cryptographic random number generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163367.aspx) (based on Microsoft's [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)).

```
class Lottery
{
    // Use Random if this is in a school project or toy application
    // private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    // Use CryptoRandom if you're dealing with real money or prizes
    private CryptoRandom randomGenerator = new CryptoRandom();

    //method which takes in a number limit and amount of numbers to be drawn
    public String drawNumbers(int numLimit, int numAmount) 
    {
        return drawNumbers(1, numLimit, numAmount);
    }

    // takes the minimum and maximum lottery numbers and how many numbers to draw
    public String drawNumbers(int minNumber, int maxNumber, int count)
    {
        if (maxNumber < minNumber) return string.Empty;
        int maxCount = (int)Math.Min(int.MaxValue, 1L + maxNumber - minNumber);
        if (count > maxCount) count = maxCount;
        if (count < 1) return string.Empty;
        var numbers = Infinite(() => randomGenerator.Next(minNumber, maxNumber)).Distinct().Take(count);
        return string.Join(" ", numbers);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> Infinite<T>(Func<T> generator)
    {
        while (true)
            yield return generator();
    }

    private class CryptoRandom
    {
        private readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider _rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        private readonly byte[] _uint32Buffer = new byte[4];
        public int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
        {
            if (minValue == maxValue) return minValue;
            long diff = (long)maxValue - minValue;
            const long Max = 1L + uint.MaxValue;
            long randLimit = Max - (Max % diff);
            uint rand;
            do {
                _rng.GetBytes(_uint32Buffer);
                rand = BitConverter.ToUInt32(_uint32Buffer, 0);
            } while (rand >= randLimit);
            return (int)(minValue + (rand % diff));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but I use a Method named M_Randomizer created by me.

```
using System;
class Randomizer
{
    public int[] M_Randomizer(int x)
    {
        bool b = false;
        if (x < -1)
        {
            b = true;
            x = -1 * x;
        }
        if(x == -1)
            x = 0;
        if (x < 2)
            return new int[x];

        int[] site;
        int k = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 2;
        if (x == 2)
        {
            site = new int[2];
            site[0] = k;
            site[1] = 1 - site[0];
            return site;
        }
        else if (x == 3)
        {
            site = new int[3];
            site[0] = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next(0, 3);
            site[1] = (site[0] + k + 1) % 3;
            site[2] = 3 - (site[0] + site[1]);
            return site;
        }
        site = new int[x];
        int a = 0, m = 0, n = 0, tmp = 0;
        int[] p = M_Randomizer(3);
        int[] q;

        if (x % 3 == 0)
            q = M_Randomizer(x / 3);
        else
            q = M_Randomizer((x / 3) + 1);
        if (k == 0)
        {
            for (m = 0; m < q.Length; m++)
            {
                for (n = 0; n < p.Length && a < x; n++)
                {
                    tmp = (q[m] * 3) + p[n];
                    if (tmp < x)
                    {
                        site[a] = tmp;
                        a++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (n < p.Length)
            {
                while (a < x)
                {
                    tmp = (q[m] * 3) + p[n];
                    if (tmp < x)
                    {
                        site[a] = tmp;
                        a++;
                    }
                    m = m + k;
                    if (m >= q.Length)
                        break;
                }
                m = m % q.Length;
                n++;
            }
        }

        a = (new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 2) + 1;
        k = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 10;
        if (k > 5)
            for (int i = a; i < k; i++)
                while (a < site.Length)
                {
                    if (k % (a + 1) == 0)
                    {
                        tmp = site[a - 1];
                        site[a - 1] = site[a];
                        site[a] = tmp;
                    }
                    a = a + 2;
                }

        k = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 10;
        if (k > 5)
        {
            n = x / 2;
            k = 0;
            if (x % 2 != 0)
                k = (new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 2);

            p = new int[n + k];
            m = (x - n) - k;
            for (a = 0; m < x; a++, m++)
                p[a] = site[m];

            m = n + k;
            for (a = (x - m) - 1; a >= 0; a--, m++)
                site[m] = site[a];

            for (a = 0; a < p.Length; a++)
                site[a] = p[a];
        }

        int[] site2;
        int[] site3 = new int[x];
        if (b)
            return site;
        else
            site2 = M_Randomizer(-1 * x);

        for (a = 0; a < site.Length; a++)
            site3[site2[a]] = site[a];

        return site3;
    }

    public int[] M_Randomizer(int x, int start)
    {
        int[] dm = M_Randomizer(x);

        for(int a = 0; a < x; a++)
            dm[a] = dm[a] + start;

        return dm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the fastest way, but I came up with this solution:

```cs
public int[] GetRandomNumber(int from, int to)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> numbers = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    for(int n = from; n <= to; n++)
    {
        numbers.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(r.Next(1, int.MaxValue), n));
    }

    return numbers.OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would keep it simple:

```
private Random _rnd = new Random();
public String drawNumbers(int numLimit, int numAmount) 
{
    return String.Join("," ,
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, numLimit)
            .OrderBy(x => _rnd.Next())
            .Take(numAmount));
}
```

Keep the declaration of the `Random` instance outside of the method to prevent returning identical sequences if you call the method in quick succession.

Answer (score -2):

Lots of ways to do this. You could sort and then compare `if array[i] == array[i+1]`.