# Random records extracted from a large CSV file

Tags: csv

I have 50 CSV files, up to 2 millions records in each.

**I daily need to get 10000 random records from each of the 50 files and make a new CSV files with all the info (10000*50)**

I can not do it manually, because will take me a lot of time, also I've tried to use Access, but, because database is larger then 2G, I cannot use it.
Also, I've tried to use CSVed - a good soft, but still did not help me.

Could someone please give an idea/soft in order to get random records from files and make a new CSV file?

Comment: This is not related to Excel, as you would not get passed through the limit of ~1M rows. Also, this would be a perfect question for another site, dedicated to [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Isn't this something that can be done pretty easily in some version of awk?

Answer (score 3):

There are many languages you could use, I would use C# and do this.

1) Get the number of lines in a file.

[Lines in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file)

2) Generate the 10,000 random numbers (unique if you need that) based on the maximum being the count from step 1.

[Random without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931528/random-number-generator-with-no-duplicates)

3) Pull the records from step 2 from the file and write to new file.

4) Repeat for each file.

Other options if you want to consider a database other than Access are MySQL or SQL Server Express to name a couple.