# Loop multiple images through multiple pictureboxes

Tags: c#, image, loops, picturebox, shuffle

I would like to display four images at the same time and upon form load the images switch places. Currently, images will appear in different numbers, for example: 1 image will appear or 2 images, etc up 4. I also want to ensure that no duplicates will appear.

Code from Form1_Load:

```
PictureBox[] boxes = new PictureBox[4];

boxes[0] = pictureBox0;
boxes[1] = pictureBox1;
boxes[2] = pictureBox2;
boxes[3] = pictureBox3;

for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
{
    int switcher = r.Next(0, 5);

    switch (switcher)
    {
        case 0:
            { boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog0; } break;
        case 1:
            { boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog1; } break;
        case 2:
            { boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog2; } break;
        case 3:
            { boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog3; } break;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
Two examples given above as to what currently happens.

**Update - Working**

The program now moves images around upon Load and there are no duplicates :)

```
List<Bitmap> resources = new List<Bitmap>();
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog0);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog1);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog2);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog3);

resources = resources.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < resources.Count; i++)
{
    pictureBox0.Image = resources[0];
    pictureBox1.Image = resources[1];
    pictureBox2.Image = resources[2];
    pictureBox3.Image = resources[3];
}
```

[image]
[image]

Two example given above showing what happens now that it works.

Comment: create array of images and shuffle it. iterate through that array. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26931594/4767498

Comment: check one more [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39310462/6290553) :)

Comment: The for loop in your update is absolutely not necessary. It just points the same resource to a picturebox four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is quite simple. Firstly, you need to shuffle the array and then iterate through it. [*Fisher–Yates shuffle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Create a method `ShuffleImages` as below:

```
public void ShuffleImages(PictureBox[] img)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < img.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = r.Next(i, img.Length);
        PictureBox temp = img[j];
        img[j] = img[i];
        img[i] = temp;                
    }
}
```

and call the method in your `Form1_Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox[] boxes = new PictureBox[4];
    boxes[0] = pictureBox0;
    boxes[1] = pictureBox1;
    boxes[2] = pictureBox2;
    boxes[3] = pictureBox3;

    ShuffleImages(boxes); //call the method

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                {  boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog0;  }
                break;
            case 1:
                {  boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog1;  }
                break;
            case 2:
                {  boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog2;  }
                break;
            case 3:
                {  boxes[i].Image = Properties.Resources.dog3;  }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: shuffled_imgs]

Answer (score 1):

As M.kazem Ahkhary points out you need to shuffle the images:

```
List<Bitmap> resources = new List<Bitmap>();
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog0);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog1);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog2);
resources.Add(Properties.Resources.dog3);

resources = resources.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList(); // Dirty but effective shuffle method

pictureBox0.Image = resources[0];
pictureBox1.Image = resources[1];
pictureBox2.Image = resources[2];
pictureBox3.Image = resources[3];
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I implement this?

Shall I replace anything?

Comment: Made some edits, it was not completely correct. You can normally just paste this code over your provided code

Comment: It's giving me errors one from each of the "resources.Add"s about not being able to convert Bitmap to String and the other error is Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 

and that "resource" doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: I updated the answer. The resources list had to be a list of Bitmaps I think and the orderdEnumerable had to be converted to a List. Last, it was resources and not resource for the appointing of the Image properties.

Comment: @stefchri, consider using `someRandom.Next(someInt)` instead of `Guid.NewGuid()`. Do you have any reason to use NewGuid and not   Random class as a random "generator?

Comment: @GianPaolo https://dotnetfiddle.net/KHK5XY shows that Guid.NewGuid() in orderby is more performant.

Comment: @GeckoIT note It can be that NewGuid is "less random" than Random.Next(): sorting a list that is already "more ordered" is quicker. Anyway, both do the trick, I prefer using Random

Comment: Random is indeed the best way I concur