# System OutOfMemoryException when generating array of random numbers

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, memory

I'm trying to create a large array of random numbers using LINQ.

I want to generate 1,000,000 numbers ranging from 1 - 2147483647.

The following code works well for small numbers:

```
    int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 2147483647)
                              .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                              .Take(num)
                              .ToArray();
```

But produces a System.OutOfMemory exception when trying to generate a large array.

What's the best way to achieve what I am looking for?

Edit: 
Thanks for the help so far, I'll write why I'm doing this and my full program code:

Regarding the array, it should not contain duplicates.

I am writing a program that will iterate through all the numbers, pair them up and return the pair with the smallest difference between them. Or return a list of all pairs with the smallest difference if their are duplicates.

Full program code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Keep running until close
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number:");
            Console.WriteLine(ClosestNumbers(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())));
        }
    }

    public static string ClosestNumbers(int num)
    {
        string returnString = "\n\nRandom numbers:\n";
        returnString += "---------------------------------------\n";

        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Generate array of {num} random numbers ranging from 1 to 2147483647.
        int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
                                  .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next(1, 2147483647))
                                  .Take(num)
                                  .ToArray();

        //returnString += string.Join(",", numbers.ToArray()) + "\n";

        // Array format: {num1, num2, difference}
        List<int[]> pairedDifferences = new List<int[]>();

        int endPoint = numbers.Length;
        int difference = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < endPoint - 1; i++)
        {

            for (int a = i + 1; a < endPoint; a++)
            {

                if (numbers[i] > numbers[a])
                {
                    difference = numbers[i] - numbers[a];
                }
                else
                {
                    difference = numbers[a] - numbers[i];
                }

                pairedDifferences.Add(new int[] { numbers[i], numbers[a], difference });

            }

        }

        int minDiff = pairedDifferences.Min(x => x[2]);

        List<int[]> minDiffsList = pairedDifferences.Where(x => x[2] == minDiff).ToList();

        returnString += "---------------------------------------\n\n\n";
        returnString += "Smallest difference(s) found between:\n\n";            

        foreach (int[] minDiffItem in minDiffsList)
        {
            // minDiffItem[0];      // first num
            // minDiffItem[1];      // second num
            // minDiffItem[2];      // difference

            returnString += $"{minDiffItem[0]} and {minDiffItem[1]}, with a difference of {minDiffItem[2]}.\n";
        }

        returnString += "\n\n\n===================================================================\n";
        returnString += "===================================================================\n\n\n";

        return returnString;
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

I'm now getting another OutOfMemory exception at the 
`pairedDifferences.Add(new int[] { numbers[i], numbers[a], difference });`
line. Does anyone know a better way to do this? Sorry this is the first time I'm doing something like this.

Comment: Sounds like AB problem, can you share why you need to create array of random numbers this big ?

Comment: "I want to generate 1,000,000 numbers ranging from 1 - 2147483647." Excluding duplicates?

Comment: This post can help you understand the limits of an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold

Comment: Yes excluding duplicates. And I am writing a program that will iterate through all the numbers, pair them up and return the pair with the smallest difference between them. Or return a list of all pairs with the smallest difference if their are duplicates.

Comment: @BenMurphy And do you need the random numbers to be equally balanced in the array. i.e. Only 1 random number in the [1..2147483647 / 1000000] range for instance, or there might be more than 1 random number within this range?

Comment: @vc74 So long as there are 1,000,000 numbers within the 1 - 2147483647 range with no duplicates, that's the only rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is poorly optimized. The `Random` class lets you specify a range from which you take a random number. That way you don't need to order everything, which is very expensive. Try this

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
                          .Select(i => rnd.Next(1, 2147483647))
                          .ToArray();
```

**Edit:**

It was previously unclear that duplicates are not allowed. If that is the case, I would add a `HashSet` to keep track of the already contained numbers, **if** the number of obtained random numbers is considerably smaller than the range they have to be in, which is the case here.

```
var memory = new HashSet<int>();
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
                          .Select(i =>
                          {
                               int number;
                               do
                               {
                                    number = rnd.Next(1, 2147483647);
                               } while (memory.Contains(number));
                               return number;
                          })
                          .ToArray();
```

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931528/random-number-generator-with-no-duplicates) for more on generating random numbers without duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked, but now I'm getting another OutOfMemory exception at the `pairedDifferences.Add(new int[] { numbers[i], numbers[a], difference });` line. Do you know a better way to do this? Sorry this is the first time I'm doing something like this.

Comment: At this point you are trying to add `10^6*10^6` elements to the list `pairedDifference`, which is simply unreasonable. Try to think about solving the problem in different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the random number generation to be balanced, you can use the following code:

```
const int rangeCount = 1_000_000;
int rangeSize = 2_147_483_647 / rangeCount;

int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, rangeCount)
                          .Select(rangeIndex => 
                           {
                             int from = ((rangeIndex - 1) * rangeSize) + 1;
                             int to = from + rangeSize;

                             return rnd.Next(from, to);
                           })
                          .ToArray();
```

which should produce 1 random number for each 2147483647 / 1000000 numbers range.

Answer (score -2):

It has to do with the OrderBy function. That is a O(n) on memory usage, that is your problem.

O(n) constitutes a linear memory usage. So more input means linearly more memory.