# Problem with getting the correct controller model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, xml-parsing

For the task I have to download several items from several xml documents (RssReader) then display random 4 elements on the page. I have already done all the code, the only problem is that the page displays the same 4 items, if I set the trap in the debuggeer in the view/controller everything loads correctly. I do not know what the problem may be, it's my beginnings in ASP.NET for all the clues to the code, thank you very much!

View code:

```
<table class="table">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Title
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.PubDate
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Model Code:

```
public class RssItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PubDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    // GET: Portfolio
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var linkList = new List<string> {
                "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=pl&gl=PL&ceid=PL:pl",
                "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=pl&gl=PL&ceid=PL:pl",
                "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=pl&gl=PL&ceid=PL:pl",
                "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=pl&gl=PL&ceid=PL:pl"
            };

        List<RssItem> rssItems = new List<RssItem>();
        List<RssItem> randomRSS = new List<RssItem>();

        foreach (string linkRss in linkList)
        {
            XElement xml = XElement.Load(linkRss);
            var query = xml.Descendants("item").Select(item =>
                         new RssItem
                         {
                             Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                             PubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                rssItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomInt = random.Next(rssItems.Count);
            randomRSS.Add(rssItems[randomInt]);
        }

        return View(randomRSS);
    }
}
```

Without traps in debugger:
[image: Without traps in debugger]

With traps in view and controller (debugger mode):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do four requests? You can take the items from a single request and display random 4. But in order for `Random` to work it needs to be outside the `for` loop.

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    int randomInt = random.Next(rssItems.Count);
    randomRSS.Add(rssItems[randomInt]);
}
```

But you could still end up with duplicates if you do not remove the rss from the list since random can create duplicates, see this answer for solutions
[Random number generator with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931528/random-number-generator-with-no-duplicates)

Comment: Placing random outside the loop solves the problem! thank you very much! Following the advice I will make a code without 4 requests