# Out of string space in VisualBasic

Tags: string, vb6

When performing the replace operation over a string I got an error: 'out of string space'

Comment: Example code? We're not mind readers here.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93932/out-of-string-space-in-visual-basic-6 is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524%28VS.60%29.aspx) (for VBA, but usually similar for VB6):

*# Expressions requiring that temporary strings be created for evaluation may cause this error. For example, the following code causes an Out of string space error on some operating systems:

```
MyString = "Hello"
For Count = 1 To 100
    MyString = MyString & MyString
Next Count
```

Assign the string to a variable of another name.*

So if you're doing something like (might not gotten the syntax correctly):

```
myStr = Replace(myStr, "from", "to")
```

Maybe you can do something like this instead:

```
dim temp as String
temp = Replace(myStr, "from", "to")
myStr = temp
```